# SetAttributes[f,Flat]: Why the order dependence?

Tags: function-construction, attributes

I'm experiencing a strange phenomenon. Here's a (quite artificial) test case:

The following definition work just fine:

```
f[x___Real]:={x}
g[a_,f[n_Integer]]:={a,n}
SetAttributes[f,Flat]

f[a,f[b,c]]
(*
 --> f[a,b,c]
*)

g[f[1.0],3]
(*
 --> g[{1.},3]
*)
```

As do the following (in a fresh kernel):

```
f[x___Real]:={x}
SetAttributes[f,Flat]
g[a_,f[n_Integer]]:={a,n}

f[a,f[b,c]]
(*
 --> f[a,b,c]
*)

g[f[1.0],3]
(*
 --> g[{1.},3]
*)
```

However, the following (evaluated in a fresh kernel again) hangs on the definition of `g`:

```
SetAttributes[f,Flat]
f[x___Real]:={x}
g[a_,f[n_Integer]]:={a,n}
```

Now I don't see any reason why the definition of `g` should depend on whether I've first defined `f` or first set the `Flat` attribute on it. Can anyone explain the mystery?

PS: If anyone can think of a better title, feel free to change it accordingly.

Comment: Using `TracePrint[]` on your third input in your last bit is rather telling... for that matter, try `TracePrint[f[n_Integer]]` after your second input and watch the growth from `f[n_Integer]` to `f[{}, n_Integer]` to `f[{}, {}, n_Integer]` to...

Comment: On the other hand, if you use `f[x__Real] := {x}` (i.e. `BlankSequence` instead of `BlankNullSequence`), you don't bump into the problem.

Comment: N.B. One doesn't need to do a kernel restart when trying out each code blob. Just precede each code blob with `Remove[f, g]` for a clean evaluation.

Comment: If you're going to play around with `TracePrint[]`, you probably would want to lower your value of `$IterationLimit` to a small integer, say 20. For instance: `Block[{$IterationLimit = 20}, TracePrint[f[n_Integer]]]`.

Comment: @J.M.: Actually for my tests I used "Notebook's Default Context → Unique to Each Cell Group" and just started a new section for each test.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to try to explain my best conjuecture as to how this happens, and don't even try to answer why.

There are three reasons for this behaviour:

**`SetDelayed` left hand side evaluation**

As others have mentioned, even though SetDelayed has attributes that indicate it holds the lhs, it does evaluate the head and the arguments of it, just not the expression as a whole.

**How the Attribute `Flat` affects the final evaluation of the expression**

Ok, so the evaluator is now trying to transform the expression (with head `Flat`) as a whole. It has already evaluated the head and arguments, or not, as it was supposed to. It has already flattened everything. It has already tried the `UpValues`, nothing fit.

Now it checks, in order, one `DownValue` at a time:

1* If it matches the expression as is, we're good. It applies the transformation rule.

2* If it doesn't, then it modifies the expression, gathering arguments. Tries combinations of `head[prev__, head[some__], aft__]` with args being different subsequences of arguments taken from expression. If some subexpression fits the pattern, it transforms it and restarts the process.

Example

```
In[27]:= ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, {Flat, HoldAll}];
f[b, c] := 8;
f[a, b, c, d]

Out[30]= f[a, 8, d]
```

3* If it doesn't then IT TRIES TO MATCH THE EXPRESSION `head[]` WITH NO ARGUMENTS. If it succeeds, then IT PREPENDS THE UNEVALUATED TRANSFORMATION OF `head[]` TO THE EXPRESSION AND RESTARTS THE EVALUATION PROCESS

Some examples:

```
In[18]:= ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4];
SetAttributes[{f1, f2, f3, f4}, Flat];
f1[2, 2, 2, 2] := "Yeahh";
f1[2] = "bo";
f1[] := (Print["here"]; 2);

f2[2] = "bo";
f2[2, 2, 2, 2] := "Yeahh";
f2[] := (Print["here"]; 2);

f3[] := (Print["here"]; 2);
f3[2, 2, 2, 2] := "Yeahh";
f3[2] = "bo";

f4[2, 2, 2, 2] := "Yeahh";
f4[] := (Print["here"]; 2);
f4[2] = "bo";

In[32]:= Scan[Print[DownValues[#][[All, 1]]] &, {f1, f2, f3, f4}]

During evaluation of In[32]:= {HoldPattern[f1[2,2,2,2]],HoldPattern[f1[2]],HoldPattern[f1[]]}

During evaluation of In[32]:= {HoldPattern[f2[2]],HoldPattern[f2[2,2,2,2]],HoldPattern[f2[]]}

During evaluation of In[32]:= {HoldPattern[f3[]],HoldPattern[f3[2,2,2,2]],HoldPattern[f3[2]]}

During evaluation of In[32]:= {HoldPattern[f4[2,2,2,2]],HoldPattern[f4[]],HoldPattern[f4[2]]}

In[33]:= f1[2]
f2[2]
f4[2]

Out[33]= "bo"

Out[34]= "bo"

During evaluation of In[33]:= here

During evaluation of In[33]:= here

During evaluation of In[33]:= here

Out[35]= "Yeahh"
```

So, in our case, when the expression `f[n_Integer]` fails to match the pattern `f[x___Real]`, it evaluates `f[]` to get `{}`, and tries matching `f[{}, f[n_Integer]]`, which doesn't match so it loops infinately.

If this is a case, then a good tip would be to always take care that all definitions of `Flat` symbols that match without arguments should go last...

**How the order of setting attributes matter**

`Flat` affects evaluation in 3 different moments:

1. After evaluating the arguments of an expression, it automatically
   flattens it's head
2. Changes the pattern-matching (more on this later)
3. Changes what the evaluator does when an expression didn't match a `DownValue`

The 1.th and 2.th part seems to only care about `Flat` being set at the time of evaluation.
But 3., it seems that that peculiar behaviour (see 2* and 3* above) of the evaluator trying to match the no-arguments version is PER DOWNVALUE, and it seems to me that, at the time the `DownValue` is set, MMA records somewhere if `Flat` was or not set at the time.

So, the previous `f3` example that looped infinitely wouldn't loop infinitely if the no argument version was defined while the `Flat` attribute wasn't set.

```
ClearAll[f3];
f3[] := (Print["here"]; 2);
SetAttributes[{f1, f2, f3, f4}, Flat];
f3[2, 2, 2, 2] := "Yeahh";
f3[2] = "bo";

In[65]:= f3[2]

Out[65]= "bo"
```

The previous `f4` example would also differ. You don't even need to set the Flat attribute back up in the end for the behaviour to remain

```
In[66]:= ClearAll[f4];
SetAttributes[f4, Flat];
f4[2, 2, 2, 2] := "Yeahh";
ClearAttributes[f4, Flat];
f4[] := (Print["here"]; 2);
SetAttributes[f4, Flat];
f4[2] = "bo";

In[73]:= f4[2]

Out[73]= "bo"
```

The same actually applies to (see 2*) the evaluator testing the different combinations of gathered arguments... So

```
In[37]:= ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, {Flat, HoldAll}];
f[b, c] := 8;
ClearAttributes[f, Flat];
f[e, g] := 9;
f[a, b, c, d]
f[a, e, g, d]

Out[42]= f[a, 8, d]

Out[43]= f[a, e, g, d]
```

**Extra for less incompleteness**

`Flat` also affects the pattern matcher.
When the pattern matcher finds itself comparing arguments of an expression whose head (let's call it `head`) has attribute `Flat`, it behaves differently: patterns of length one (`_`, `r_`, `Condition`s, `PatternTest`s) trigger the pattern matcher to automatically wrap a `head` around the respective arguments of the expression so both the expression and the pattern have the same number of arguments (could also be a single argument, but it never leaves it as is. Don't know the purpose). In cases where more than one option is possible due to having `__s` as arguments, it just starts trying one way and if it doesn't match, tries the next).

```
In[47]:= ClearAll[f]; SetAttributes[f, {Flat, HoldAllComplete}];
         Cases[Hold@f[1], Hold@f[i_] :> Hold[i], {0}]
         Cases[Hold@f[1, 2, 3, 4], Hold@f[1, i_, 4] :> Hold[i], {0}]
         Cases[Hold@f[1, 2, 3, 4], Hold@f[i_, __] :> Hold[i], {0}]
         Cases[Hold@f[1, 2, 3, 4], 
            Hold@f[i_, j__ /; Length[{j}] === 2] :> Hold[i], {0}]

Out[48]= {Hold[f[1]]}

Out[49]= {Hold[f[2, 3]]}

Out[50]= {Hold[f[1]]}

Out[51]= {Hold[f[1, 2]]}
```

**Conclusion**

The problem is: Will the evaluation of `f[n_Integer]` in our definition of `g` trigger an infinite loop or not? It does evaluate because of the peculiar evaluation rules of `Set` functions.
`f[n_Integer]` doesn't match the only `DownValue` it has at the time: `f[x___Real]`. In the 2 cases that work, that `DownValue` wasn't defined while `f` had the attribute `Flat`, so it just returns unevaluated. However, in the third case, the `DownValue` was defined while the symbol had `Flat`. So after failing, it tries to evaluate `f[]`, returning `{}` and now reevaluates the whole expression as `f[{}, n_Integer]`

Comment: Thanks for this great post. It's really a good piece of reverse engineering. Since it finally completely answers in detail my question, I've moved the accepted answer to yours.

Comment: Totally agree with @celtschk. Great piece of work! I actually never completely understood this topic, and your investigation added some missing bits, thanks a lot.

Comment: This post was made right after the confusion of testing and testing, and it is more confusing than necessary. I should edit it some time

Answer (score 15):

Generally, a good advice would be to set attributes *before* giving definitions to the function.

The *difference* in your case is caused by the effect that I call *evaluation during assignments*. There was a  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408310/unwanted-evaluation-in-assignments-in-mathematica-why-it-happens-and-how-to-de) devoted to it in the past, where I contributed an answer with a detailed analysis of the problem. I also mentioned this problem in my [recent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues/127#127). The bottom line is that functions generally *do* evaluate inside the l.h.s. of `SetDelayed`, using those definitions that they already have by that moment.

As to *why* things hang, I can offer some analysis but no explanation. Let's trace it:

```
ClearAll[f, g];
SetAttributes[f, {Flat}]
f[x___Real] := (If[n++ > 5, Throw[$Failed]])
```

Now,

```
In[150]:= Block[{n=0},Trace[Catch@f[1],_f]]
Out[150]= 
{{f[1],f[If[n++>5,Throw[$Failed]],1],f[Null,1],
f[If[n++>5,Throw[$Failed]],Null,1],f[Null,Null,1],f[If[n++>5,Throw[$Failed]],Null,Null,1],
f[Null,Null,Null,1],f[If[n++>5,Throw[$Failed]],Null,Null,Null,1],
f[Null,Null,Null,Null,1],f[If[n++>5,Throw[$Failed]],Null,Null,Null,Null,1],
f[Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,1],f[If[n++>5,Throw[$Failed]],Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,1],
f[Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,1],
f[If[n++>5,Throw[$Failed]],Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,1]}}
```

You can see that the function is applied as `f[arg] -> f[arg, result-of-previous-computation-of-f]`, and since your pattern allows for any number of arguments, it never stops. This may be a bug, or may be I do not understand `Flat` attribute sufficiently well.

Comment: @J.M. Good point about `TracePrint`! I forgot about this possibility.

Comment: I think it's more the combination of `Flat` and `BlankNullSequence` that does the function in...

Comment: @J.M. Yes, but the effect is observed during the evaluation of an assignment for `g`, and *that*  happens because `f` inside of the l.h.s. evaluates.

Comment: +1 `TimeConstrained` is also useful in tracing situations such as this.  For example, try `TracePrint[TimeConstrained[f[n_Integer], 0.005]]` using the original definition of `f`.  Adjust the constant `0.005` to match the speed of your CPU.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation (and the links to the other posts; that was quite a lot of informative reading). I now definitively understand more about how Mathematica works.

Comment: @WReach Thanks for the hint ( I seldom use `TracePrint` and was unaware of this trick either), and also for the upvote. It's good that you are here. Many questions here would benefit from your answers.

Comment: @celtschk You are most welcome. As to the behavior of `f`, I don't quite understand it myself yet.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: From the fact that no other answer has popped up, I conclude that I'll not get any more information about why `f` behaves this way, therefore I've now accepted your answer.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks for the accept. Once some more informative answer gets added here, you can always checkmark that one instead.