# Constructing a function with Flat and OneIdentity attribute with the property that otimes[a]:>a

Tags: function-construction

I want to have a function (called `otimes`) with the following two properties:

1. it has the attribute `OneIdentity` and `Flat`
2. if evaluated with a single argument it returns that argument

The built-in function `Times` has these properties; e.g., evaluating `Times[a]` yields `a`.

I am struggling with implementing my own function having the same behavior. What I tried is the obvious implementation

```
SetAttributes[otimes,{OneIdentity,Flat}]
otimes[a_]:=a
```

However this does not work and leads to an infinite recursion when I evaluate

```
otimes[a,b]
```

I do not know how to implement the desired behavior consistently. Maybe somebody can help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you might want to look into `NonCommutativeMultiply`. The very purpose of this function is to allow the user to set up their own version of multiplication.  It already has the attribute `OneIdentity`.

Comment: What's the code that leads to the undesired infinite recursion?

Comment: @MarkMcClure: it also does not work with NonCommutativeMultiply. NonCommutativeMultiply[a] remains unevaluated.

Comment: @Rojo: otimes[anything]

Comment: I still don't understand the question. In particular, `MatchQ[b, otimes[a_]]` yields the same as `MatchQ[b, Times[a_]]`. So could you state more clearly what the problem is that gives infinite recursion?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried to find a minimal example and it was too minimal (and I did not see that some old Attributes were still set). I edit the question...

Comment: Can you edit the `otimes` part out of your title? Without any idea of what `otimes` is (which is mentioned only in the body), it is meaningless in the title...

Comment: @Fabian: From the name of the function, I think he actually wants `CircleTimes`. Of course he would have to add the definitions anyway; the only special thing about `CircleTimes` is that it displays as infix `⊗` (or as prefix if there is only one argument; but then, that case would be handled by his one-argument definition anyway).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see now. The problem arises with `Flat` then. Just set the attributes after setting the definitions. Or at least the `Flat` attribute

```
ClearAll[otimes];
SetAttributes[otimes, OneIdentity]
otimes[a_] := a
SetAttributes[otimes, Flat]
```

Check out [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/776/109) for more details on why this works.

Basically, MMA remembers if the symbol was `Flat` or not at the time each `DownValue` is defined. The infinite recursion is more related to this:

```
SetAttributes[f, Flat];
Replace[Hold@f[2], Hold@f[i_] :> Hold[i]]
```

So, when you did `otimes[2]` and it checked the `otimes[a_]:=a` downvalue, it matched `a` with `otimes[2]`, so you got your infinite recursion

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

I came up with a better answer in my response to [(174384)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174384/45431), and since that question was closed as a duplicate of this question, I thought it might be nice to include it here. Basically, one can avoid the iteration error caused by the [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) pattern matcher by inserting a [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim) into the definition. So use:

```
SetAttributes[otimes, {OneIdentity, Flat}];
Verbatim[otimes][a_] := a
```

Examples:

```
otimes[a, b]
otimes[a]
```

> otimes[a, b]
>
> a

**Original answer**

Another possibility is to use something like:

```
SetAttributes[otimes, {OneIdentity,Flat}]
a_otimes /; Length[Unevaluated[a]]==1 := First @ Unevaluated @ a
```

Then,

```
otimes[a]
```

> a

No recursion issues!

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing a bit at what you're doing here, so I do hope some of this is relevant. Trying to define your own version of multiplication is essentially trying to implement a group structure in mathematics.  Here's how I would implement the dihedral group using `NonCommutativeMultiply`.  At the end, you'll notice that I do need to deal with expressions like `NonCommutativeMultiply[a]`.

The dihedral group of order $2n$ has presentation
$$\langle a,b : a^2=b^2=(ab)^n=1 \rangle.$$

Given a finite string of $a$s and $b$s representing an element of the dihedral group, there is a standard procedure to place that string into one of the following four canonical forms: $(ab)^m$, $(ab)^m b$, $(ba)^m$, or ($ba)^m a$, where $m$ is an integer such that $0\leq m<n$.  To do so, simply remove each consecutive pair of identical symbols and then reduce the exponent of $ab$ or $ba$ modulo $n$.  This solves the so called Word Problem for the dihedral group.

To implement this in Mathematica, first associate `UpValues` with `a` and `b` representing the order of those elements.

```
a /: a ** a = 1;
b /: b ** b = 1;
a /: a ** 1 = a;
b /: b ** 1 = b;
a /: 1 ** a = a;
b /: 1 ** b = b;
```

Now, let's generate a long product of $a$s and $b$s.

```
SeedRandom[1];
w = NonCommutativeMultiply @@ RandomChoice[{a, b}, 100]
```

a ** b ** a ** b ** a ** b ** a ** b ** a ** b ** a ** b ** a ** b ** a ** b

The result is much shorter than 100 because cancellation has already occurred.  Now let's put it in it's final form. Assuming you're working in $D_6$, you can do the following:

```
n = 3;
finalForm[w : NonCommutativeMultiply[a, ___, b]] :=
  (a ** b)^Mod[Length[w]/2, n];
finalForm[w : NonCommutativeMultiply[a, ___, a]] :=
  (a ** b)^Mod[(Length[w] - 1)/2, n] ** a;
finalForm[w : NonCommutativeMultiply[b, ___, a]] :=
  (b ** a)^Mod[Length[w]/2, n];
finalForm[w : NonCommutativeMultiply[b, ___, b]] :=
  (b ** a)^Mod[(Length[w] - 1)/2, n] ** b;
finalForm[w]
```

(a ** b)^2

Well, that's cool but what about this example:

```
finalForm[a ** a ** a]
```

finalForm[a]

We've run into exactly the problem you've described.  To fix it, simply associate `DownValues` with `finalForm`.

```
finalForm[a] = a;
finalForm[b] = b;
finalForm[a ** a ** a]
```

a

More generally, you might define a function `simplify` with the property that

```
simplify[NonCommutativeMultiply[a_]] := a
```

Comment: Thanks for your question. I figured out that my example was a bit to minimal. I changed the question such that now it is clear where the infinite recursion appears.

Comment: This is off-topic for the question, but by any chance do you have any insight into this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/132553/2283)?

Comment: @rcollyer Can't you see I've got only 196 cred on mathematics.SE?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. But, you're the first mathematician (other than J.M, despite his protests that he isn't one) about this question, and with the use of group theory above, I thought maybe you may have some insight into the issue.

Comment: As to having a rep of 196, not any more. :)

Comment: @rcollyer Aren't there rules against this sort of thing? :)

Comment: I won't tell if you won't.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question it's an issue I sent to MathGroup about ten years ago. Alan Hayes solved it for me, and it's all discused at http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_A-K_27.html
Go there and read the part, "A problem with the Flat attribute and how to solve it".

Comment: Thank you: this is exactly the problem I was suffering. In fact, I did know that Flat affects the pattern matching but I did not know that for a pattern only the attributes at the time when it is set are important and that the attributes are then stored.