# Functions in a different context are replaced with infix forms of their namesake in System`

Tags: functions, output-formatting, syntax, contexts

So, in an attempt to help out Fabian [with his question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/similar-behavior-as-times-for-function-with-property-oneidentity), I did what I often do, and created a new symbol in the `` Pillsy` `` package that I could play with. Since it was in a package I control completely, I thought, "Hey, I can just call it `Times`!". I was really surprised when this happened:

```
In[3]:= Pillsy`Times[a, b, c]
Out[3]= a * b * c
```

It looks like Mathematica uses just the symbol name in determining whether to replace something with infix syntax, without paying attention to the context. However, I'm fairly sure I've never seen it happen before and I don't recall coming across it in the documentation. Evidently specifying `InputForm` shows you the whole thing:

```
In[4]:= Pillsy`Times[a, b, c] // InputForm
Out[4]= Pillsy`Times[a, b, c]
```

This is in contrast to the `InputForm` for `` System`Times ``.

Is this an intentional feature (it's hard to imagine otherwise), and if so, how does it interact with things like `MakeBoxes`, `MakeExpression` and `Format`?

Also, how do you avoid being burned by it? I'm a little alarmed that my assumption that  `a * b * c` is the same thing as `` System`Times[a, b, c] `` is unfounded, even in the absence of changes to `$Post` and the like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the StandardForm (default for output) of `Times` in any context (or `Plus`, etc) is with the * and + symbols.

But your assumption isn't wrong I think, the symbols * and + are mapped to System Times and System Plus. Try

```
PrependTo[$ContextPath, "blo`"];
blo`Times[a_, b_] := 8;

FullForm@MakeExpression[RowBox[{"a", "*", "b"}], StandardForm]
```

I think that this goes against Mathematica policy that "StandardForm generates output that gives a unique and unambiguous representation of Mathematica expressions, suitable for use as input"

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with `ToBoxes`:

```
Outer[#1[#2[a,b]]&,{ToString[#,OutputForm]&,ToBoxes},{Times,foo`Times}]
(*
==> {{"a b", "foo`Times[a, b]"}, {\(a\ b\), \(a * b\)}}
*)
```

Note that `Times` and `` foo`Times `` are still different in that for `Times`, no `*` is generated.

When typing to the kernel directly, `OutputForm` is used, and `` foo`Times[a,b] `` gets printed:

```
In[1]:= {Times[a,b], foo`Times[a,b]}

Out[1]= {a b, foo`Times[a, b]}
```

Comment: If you try it with `Plus` the + is generated for both