# Recursion depth exceeded in pattern matching with attribute Flat

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, attributes, infinite-loop

I am defining a linear associative multiplication operation `Mult[]`:

```
ClearAll[Mult]
SetAttributes[Mult, {Flat, OneIdentity}];
Mult[A___, a_, B___] := a Mult[A, B] /; NumberQ[a]
```

Then I try to evaluate a simple expression, which (I believe) does not match the rule written above:

```
Mult[X, Y]
```

I got the error `Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded`. It is definitely related to the attribute `Flat`, but I do not see how. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html) hard to work with.  Despite seeing it in use numerous times I'm never *quite* sure what it will do until I try it, so maybe I'm not the person to answer your question.  Nevertheless I shall try.

Consider this related, reduced example:

```
Attributes[foo] = {Flat, OneIdentity};
foo[a_] := "inert" /; Print @ HoldForm[a]

foo[X, Y];
```

> ```
> foo[X,Y]
>
> X
>
> Y
> ```

Critically the entire expression `foo[X, Y]` is substituted for the pattern `a_` in one of the match attempts.  This leads to infinite recursion.

One way to get around this is to prevent evaluation of that expression, which is what I used [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) for above.  Applied to your original function:

```
ClearAll[Mult]
Attributes[Mult] = {Flat, OneIdentity};
Mult[A___, a_, B___] := a Mult[A, B] /; NumberQ[Unevaluated @ a]

Mult[X, Y]

Mult[3, x, 7, y, z]
```

> ```
> Mult[X, Y]
>
> 21 Mult[x, y, z]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

This is basically a duplicate of question [(5067)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5067/45431). You can use my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157892/45431) to that question to resolve your issue:

```
ClearAll[Mult]
SetAttributes[Mult, {Flat, OneIdentity}];
Verbatim[Mult][A___, a_, B___] := a Mult[A,B] /; NumberQ[a]
```

Then:

```
Mult[X, Y]
Mult[3, X, 7, Y, Z]
```

> Mult[X, Y]
>
> 21 Mult[X, Y, Z]

No recursion errors.

**Comparison**

Using [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim) should be much quicker than the accepted answer, because those patterns where `a` gets matched with a `Mult` object should never happen. The accepted answer (using `Mult2`):

```
ClearAll[Mult2]
Attributes[Mult2] = {Flat, OneIdentity};
Mult2[A___, a_, B___] := a Mult2[A,B] /; NumberQ[Unevaluated@a]
```

And a comparison:

```
SeedRandom[1]
r = RandomChoice[Join[Alphabet[], Range[10]], 30];

r1 = Mult @@ r; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Mult2 @@ r; //AbsoluteTiming

ReplaceAll[Mult->List] @ r1 === ReplaceAll[Mult2->List] @ r2
```

> {0.000206, Null}
>
> {0.025536, Null}
>
> True

Comment: I'm probably missing an important point here but isn't this like leaving out `Flat` to begin with?  Doesn't an actual solution need to *preserve* that pattern-matching behavior?  (I am assuming that this is a toy example and not the actual, complete problem.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Flat has two main characteristics, pattern matching and associativity. The pattern matching is interfering with the DownValues, so using Verbatim disables it. The associativity still works, e.g., `Mult[a, Mult[b, c]]` still evaluates to `Mult[a, b, c]`.

Comment: I can't think of an example where that pattern behavior is needed within the definition itself but I suspect one exists.  Nevertheless for the case at hand I see the superiority of your method.  Do you think this question should be closed as a duplicate of 5067?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Perhaps a related comment would be sufficient? I think it's slightly different.

Comment: Okay.  The content of your post already includes 5067 in the **Linked** bar to the right.