# How to construct infix operator with usual behavior?

Tags: evaluation, syntax, operators

I am trying to define my own infix operator and having problems with strung-together evaluation. The code below is a simple example. What I would like is to have the operator treated associatively, but that fails.

```
(* define our own dot product *)

x_⊙y_ := x.y

(* and some tensors *)

x = {4, 5};

y = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

z = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}};

(* the usual dot product evaluates in order *)

z.y.x

(* {124,170} *)

(* but ours does not *)

z⊙y⊙x

(* {{2,3},{3,4}}⊙{{1,2},{3,4}}⊙{4,5} *)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the attributes of [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot):

```
Attributes[Dot]
```

> {Flat, OneIdentity, Protected}

The combination of [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) and [`OneIdentity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OneIdentity) is what takes care of associativity for [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot), so do the same with [`CircleDot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircleDot):

```
SetAttributes[CircleDot, {Flat, OneIdentity}];
CircleDot[x_, y_] := x . y
```

Now, [`CircleDot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircleDot) should have the associativity you desire:

```
z ⊙ y ⊙ x
```

> {124, 170}

**Addendum**

Addressing the comments.

1. I think this is the canonical way to create an associative operator.
2. If you want to create a left-associative or right-associative operator, then you do not want to use the [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) attribute. An operator that is [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) will satisfy:

   ```
   f[x, y, z] === f[f[x, y], z] === f[x, f[y, z]]
   ```

which is clearly neither left nor right associative.

3. Operators like [`LeftTee`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeftTee) achieve left-associativity through parsing. For example, the input:

   ```
   Hold[x ⊣ y ⊣ z] //FullForm
   ```

> Hold[LeftTee[LeftTee[x,y],z]]

does not parse to `LeftTee[x, y, z]`. In fact, syntax coloring gives a clue about this:

[image]

That is, [`LeftTee`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeftTee) should only be used as a binary operator. On the other hand, [`CircleDot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircleDot) does parse to the [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) version:

```
Hold[x ⊙ y ⊙ z] //FullForm
```

> Hold[CircleDot[x,y,z]]

Comment: Is this the canonical way?  I try to avoid setting these attributes unless they are specifically needed as they affect pattern matching in ways I don't always understand, or at least anticipate, e.g. [(143836)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143836/121), [(18060)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18060/121), [(71494)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71494/121).  Is it logical to conclude that one wants these pattern matching changes if simple left-associativity is desired?  If so why doesn't e.g `LeftTee` have these by default?

Comment: Thanks, Carl. This does work. It is interesting that the attributes must be set before defining the operator. Setting its attributes after defining its functionality does not work. (I am also interested in Mr.Wizard's comment.)

Answer (score 2):

You can include your own associativity rule:

```
x_⊙y_ := x.y
x_⊙y_⊙z__ := (x⊙y)⊙z

z⊙y⊙x
```

> ```
> {124, 170}
> ```

Or pick [an operator](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) that natively has the desired associativity:

```
x_ ⊣ y_ := x.y

z ⊣ y ⊣ x
```

> ```
> {124, 170}
> ```

Recommended reading:

- [How can one define an infix operator with an arbitrary unicode character?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6355/121)
- [How is + as an infix operator associated with Plus?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31375/121)
- [How to make a binary function associative? (Or define an n-ary function?)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77913/121)