# What are Flat Attribute best practices?

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, attributes

I would like, as an example, to build a [`Times`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html)-like function.  Take the following example

```
SetAttributes[f, OneIdentity];
f[] := 1;
f[a_] := a;
SetAttributes[f, Flat];
f[a_ + b_, c_] := f[a, c] + f[b, c];
```

This works perfectly. Notice that had I grouped the Attributes, an infinite recursion would have happened:

```
SetAttributes[f, {OneIdentity,Flat}];
f[] := 1;
f[a_] := a;
f[a_ + b_, c_] := f[a, c] + f[b, c];
```

The reason why it happens is explained in several posts (for instance [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/constructing-a-function-with-flat-and-oneidentity-attribute-with-the-property-th)). 
However in Mathematica guide for `Flat` there is written:

> The Flat attribute must be assigned before defining any values for a Flat function.

My (first) example does not respect this principle but works. I would like to know if there exist an "official" best practice to implement function with `Flat` attributes. It would be nice to see the implementation of `Times`, but of course it must be hard-coded.

Answer (score 3):

Per the linked question, you could do:

```
SetAttributes[f, {Flat, OneIdentity}];
Verbatim[f][] := 1
Verbatim[f][a_] := a
f[a_ + b_, c_] := f[a, c] + f[b, c]
```

Then, there are no iteration/recursion errors:

```
f[]
f[a]
f[x, y]
f[x + y, z]
```

> 1
>
> a
>
> f[x, y]
>
> f[x, z] + f[y, z]