# How can Mathematica automatically replace NonCommutativeMultiply[x] with x for a single argument x?

Tags: pattern-matching

By default, an expression like `NoncommutativeMultiply[x]` does not simplify to `x`, unlike `Times[x]` or `Plus[x]`. My attempts to implement an automatic replacement e.g.:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply /: NonCommutativeMultiply[x_] := x;
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

tend to go into infinite loops e.g. when typing `x**y`. I understand why this is the case for a function like `NonCommutativeMultiply` with attribute `Flat`. However, I have been unable to find a way to overcome this behaviour and obtain replacements like for `Plus` and `Times`.

Similarly, I also cannot find a way to automatically replace `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` with `1` without causing infinite loops (again, `Plus` and `Times` work fine giving 0 and 1, respectively).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cannot test right now, but [`OneIdentity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OneIdentity.html) perhaps?

Answer (score 9):

@QuantumDot provided a hack that can be used to achieve your goal, but I don't think it's very robust. For instance, the cloud uses `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` to transfer definitions when needed, and the hack doesn't survive this transfer. Here's the hack:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

ClearAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply, Flat];
NonCommutativeMultiply /: NonCommutativeMultiply[x_] := x;
SetAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply, Flat];

Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

It works:

```
x**y
NonCommutativeMultiply[x]
```

> x ** y
>
> x

Now, let's see what happens when the definition is transferred using `` Language`ExtendedDefinition ``:

```
defn = Language`ExtendedDefinition[NonCommutativeMultiply]
```

> Language`DefinitionList[NonCommutativeMultiply->{OwnValues->{},SubValues->{},UpValues->{},DownValues->{HoldPattern[NonCommutativeMultiply[x_]]:>x},NValues->{},FormatValues->{},DefaultValues->{},Messages->{},Attributes->{Flat,OneIdentity,Protected}}]

Reset the definition:

```
Language`ExtendedDefinition[NonCommutativeMultiply] = defn;
```

The hack no longer works:

```
x**y
NonCommutativeMultiply[x]
```

> $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.
>
> Hold[x ** y]
>
> x

An alternative is to insert [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim) into your definition so that the [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) pattern matching (which causes the iteration error) is avoided:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
Clear[NonCommutativeMultiply]

Verbatim[NonCommutativeMultiply][a_]:=a

Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```

Then:

```
x**y
NonCommutativeMultiply[x]
```

> x ** y
>
> x

work as desired. Also, the behavior is unaffected by transferring definitions using `` Language`ExtendedDefinition ``.

Comment: The solution using Verbatim is exactly what I was looking for. This solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Very interesting.  I've never seen ``Language`ExtendedDefinition`` before.  Should I interpret its inability to transfer the definitions intact as a bug/deficit of that function?

Comment: @QuantumDot No, as I tried to imply, I think clearing and setting the Flat attribute in the way you did is relying on M behavior that is undocumented and liable to change (a hack).

Comment: Interesting--I didn't even realize this! In fact, I have written packages where I strategically set `Attributes` in the middle of package symbol definitions to get the behavior I need.  Would you say this way of writing M code is also a hack?  If so, how would you suggest I make the definitions for package symbols/functions?

Answer (score 4):

Just get rid of the `Flat` attribute before adding the definition.  Then put the attribute back.

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
ClearAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply, Flat];
NonCommutativeMultiply /: NonCommutativeMultiply[x_] := x;
SetAttributes[NonCommutativeMultiply, Flat];
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
```