# Except not working in Function

Tags: pattern-matching

I have defined the CirclePlus operator as follows:

```
Clear[CirclePlus];
SetAttributes[CirclePlus, {Orderless, Flat, OneIdentity}];
CirclePlus[a_ : Except[_CirclePlus]] := a;
CirclePlus[a_?MatrixQ, b_?MatrixQ, c___] := CirclePlus[Plus[a, b], c]
CirclePlus[a_?VectorQ, b_?VectorQ, c___] := CirclePlus[Plus[a, b], c]
CirclePlus[a_?MatrixQ, b_?NumberQ, c___] := 
 CirclePlus[Plus[a, DiagonalMatrix[Table[b, Length[a]]]], c]
```

Yet, it does not work as expected for the single argument case:

```
In: CirclePlus[1]
Out: CirclePlus[1]
```

I expected `Out: 1`. If I remove the `Except[_CirclePlus]`, I get recursion errors for other operations, but get the desired result in the above case. How can I solve this issue?

Note:
Changing it to the in the comments suggested

```
CirclePlus[a : Except[_CirclePlus]] := a;
```

Leads to an infinite recursion again:

```
Message[$IterationLimit::itlim, 4096]
```

Comment: It should be `CirclePlus[a : Except[_CirclePlus]]`.

Comment: If I do it like that, I get the recursion issue again.

Comment: That should not happen. Have you `ClearAll[CirclePlus];` and removed redundant definition(s)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructing a function with Flat and OneIdentity attribute with the property that otimes\[a\]:>a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/constructing-a-function-with-flat-and-oneidentity-attribute-with-the-property-th). See especially my answer to the question.