# Why rule does not work if Flat attribute?

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language, attributes

The following works:

```
In[39]:= ClearAttributes[M, Flat];
Replace[M[F1[a]], M[x_F1] | M[x_F2] -> x]
Replace[M[F2[a]], M[x_F1] | M[x_F2] -> x]
Replace[M[F3[a]], M[x_F1] | M[x_F2] -> x]

Out[40]= F1[a]

Out[41]= F2[a]

Out[42]= M[F3[a]]
```

the following does not

```
In[34]:= ClearAttributes[M, Flat];
SetAttributes[M, {Flat}];
Replace[M[F1[a]], M[x_F1] | M[x_F2] -> x]
Replace[M[F2[a]], M[x_F1] | M[x_F2] -> x]
Replace[M[F3[a]], M[x_F1] | M[x_F2] -> x]

Out[36]= M[F1[a]]

Out[37]= M[F2[a]]

Out[38]= M[F3[a]]
```

why?

Comment: Try adding the `OneIdentity` attribute as per `Flat` documentation.

Comment: Related: [(304)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/304/121), [(5067)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5067/121)

Comment: @ssch But `OneIdentity` is wrong. Head should not disappear.

Answer (score 4):

I researched `Flat` a little bit about a year ago when I wrote [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/776/109). It isn't as clear as can be. It needs updating, and perhaps I'll do that soon. In any case, taking the relevant paragraph:

When the pattern matcher finds itself comparing arguments of an expression whose head (let's call it `head`) has attribute `Flat`, it behaves differently: patterns of length one (`_`, `r_`, `Condition`s, `PatternTest`s) trigger the pattern matcher to automatically wrap a `head` around the respective arguments of the expression so both the expression and the pattern have the same number of arguments (could also be a single argument, but it never leaves it as is. Don't know the purpose). In cases where more than one option is possible due to having `__s` as arguments, it just starts trying one way and if it doesn't match, tries the next).

```
In[47]:= ClearAll[f]; SetAttributes[f, {Flat, HoldAllComplete}];
         Cases[Hold@f[1], Hold@f[i_] :> Hold[i], {0}]
         Cases[Hold@f[1, 2, 3, 4], Hold@f[1, i_, 4] :> Hold[i], {0}]
         Cases[Hold@f[1, 2, 3, 4], Hold@f[i_, __] :> Hold[i], {0}]
         Cases[Hold@f[1, 2, 3, 4], 
            Hold@f[i_, j__ /; Length[{j}] === 2] :> Hold[i], {0}]

Out[48]= {Hold[f[1]]}

Out[49]= {Hold[f[2, 3]]}

Out[50]= {Hold[f[1]]}

Out[51]= {Hold[f[1, 2]]}
```

**This case**

See this

```
MatchQ[M[F1[a]], M[_F1]]
MatchQ[M[F1[a]], M[_M]]

(* False *)

(* True *)
```

The fact that your blank `_F1` only matches with head `F1` doesn't change the fact that it's a blank, so it actually tries to match `M[M[F1[a]]]` to `M[_F1]` and fails. You can use `M[F1[___]]` to prevent this (or set `OneIdentity` if appropriate)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why `OneIdentity` doesn't work for you but this trick *appears* to work:

```
SetAttributes[M, Flat];

rule = M[x : Repeated[_F1, {1}]] | M[x : Repeated[_F2, {1}]] :> x;

Replace[M[F1[a]], rule]
Replace[M[F2[a]], rule]
Replace[M[F3[a]], rule]
```

> ```
> F1[a]
>
> F2[a]
>
> M[F3[a]]
> ```

Please make sure to use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) as I did above when working with named patterns on the right-hand side.