# Different behaviours of Default Argument

Tags: syntax, variable-definitions, assignment

I don't really understand the behaviour of Default Argument. If I execute this command in Mathematica:

```
In: {f[a], f[a + b]} /. f[x_ + y_.] -> p[x, y]
```

> `Out: {p[a, 0], p[b, a]}`

Why is the a and b swapped?

How can I explain the different behaviour of the above compared with the each of the following:

```
In: {f[a], f[a + b]} /. f[x_ + y_] -> p[x, y]
```

> `Out: {f[a], p[a, b]}`

```
In: {f[a], f[a + b]} /. f[x_. + y_] -> p[x, y]
```

> `Out: {p[0, a], p[a, b]}`

```
In: {f[a], f[a + b]} /. f[x_. + y_.] -> p[x, y]
```

> `Out: {p[a, 0], p[a, b]}`

And similarly for:

```
In: {f[a], f[a b]} /. f[x_ y_.] -> p[x, y]
```

> `Out: {p[a, 1], p[b, a]}`

```
In: {f[a], f[a b]} /. f[x_  y_] -> p[x, y]
```

> `Out: {f[a], p[a, b]}`

```
In: {f[a], f[a b]} /. f[x_. y_] -> p[x, y]
```

> `Out: {p[1, a], p[a, b]}`

```
In: {f[a], f[a b]} /. f[x_. y_.] -> p[x, y]
```

> `Out: {p[a, 1], p[a, b]}`

From Mathematica help, what I understand is that Mathematica will return the default value if the argument of _. is not inputted. But I still cannot make the above statements any sense. Besides the obvious observable output such as reordering, I don't really understand the logic behind _. How does it relate to sum and multiplication? When will _. be useful in other than this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: A look at the output of `TracePrint[{f[a], f[a + b]} /. f[x_ + y_.] -> p[x, y]]` shows that there is some reordering done; that is, `x_ + y_.` is automagically reordered as `y_. + x_`, since `Plus[]` is orderless, and I'm guessing `Optional[]` comes before `Pattern[]` in canonical order.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I know it is reordered, but what is the logic behind it. Why adding _. can reorder it, why it is only the first case that a and b are reordered?

Comment: I did give my guess that `Optional[]` (`y_.` is internally represented as `Optional[Pattern[y, Blank[]]]`) comes before `Pattern[]` (`x_` is internally represented as `Pattern[x, Blank[]]`) in canonical order, which is why you're seeing the reordering. But there might be a deeper explanation...

Comment: Both `Times[]` and `Plus[]` are `Orderless` (use `Attributes[]` to see this), so they both sort their arguments for the purpose of having a canonical form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question.  I see this was largely answered in the comments yesterday, but since no one posted a formal answer I shall.

Cases 2, 3, and 4 appear relatively straightforward.  (Incidentally you should be using `:>`, `RuleDelayed` here, rather than `->`, to localize the pattern names `x` and `y`.)  The first case that swaps positions needs a closer look however.  First, observe this case:

```
{f[c], f[c + b]} /. f[x_. + y_.] :> p[x, y]
```

> ```
> {p[c, 0], p[b, c]}
> ```

This is because the LHS of `/.` is evaluated before matching, and `f[c + b]` evaluates to `f[b + c]`.  This is because of the `Orderless` attribute of `Plus`.

Considering the first case, the RHS of `/.` is also evaluated, and again reordering (sorting) takes place:

```
Trace[
 {f[a], f[a + b]} /. f[x_ + y_.] :> p[x, y]
] // Column
```

> ```
> {{{x_ + y_., y_. + x_}, f[y_. + x_]}, f[y_. + x_] :> p[x, y], f[y_. + x_] :> p[x, y]}
> {f[a], f[a + b]} /. f[y_. + x_] :> p[x, y]
> {p[a, 0], p[b, a]}
> ```

Here `f[x_ + y_.]` evaluates to `f[y_. + x_]`.  You need to prevent the evaluation of `Plus` if you do not want this ordering to take place.  On the left side this can be done with `Unevaluated`:

```
Unevaluated[{f[c], f[c + b]}] /. f[x_. + y_.] :> p[x, y]
```

> ```
> {p[c, 0], p[c, b]}
> ```

It is however ineffective on the right side:

```
{f[a], f[a + b]} /. Unevaluated[f[x_ + y_.] :> p[x, y]]
```

> ```
> {p[a, 0], p[b, a]}
> ```

Surprisingly, so is `HoldPattern`:

```
{f[a], f[a + b]} /. HoldPattern[f[x_ + y_.]] :> p[x, y]
```

> ```
> {p[a, 0], p[b, a]}
> ```

I don't know why.  Perhaps there is an evaluation leak within `ReplaceAll` that causes this to evaluate anyway, or more likely I am forgetting something about the interaction of pattern matching and the `Orderless` attribute.

Comment: +1. It seems that it is a bug in pattern matcher: defining `HoldPattern@f[x_ + y_: 0] := p[x, y]` and then evaluating `f[a + b]` gives `p[b, a]`. And with `f[Unevaluated[Plus[x_, y_: 0]]] := p[x, y]` we can create the definition `f[x_+(y_:0)]:=p[x,y]`. But it also gives `p[b, a]`. The same is true for definitions `f[HoldPattern[Plus[x_, y_: 0]]] := p[x, y]` and `f[HoldPattern[Plus][x_, y_: 0]] := p[x, y]`.

Comment: @Alexey Is there perhaps some property of `Orderless` or `Flat`, etc., that would explain this?  There are aspects of the pattern matcher that are not obvious. e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18068/121

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, I don't think it's a bug. `HoldPattern` prevents *evaluation* of the pattern (compare `Unevaluated[Print[a + b]] /. HoldPattern@Print[y_ + x_] :> p[x, y]` with and without the `HoldPattern`) but I don't believe it is intended to prevent the pattern matcher from respecting the `Orderless` attribute. Remember that `ReplaceAll` is just using the first of potentially multiple ways to match the pattern. If you use `ReplaceList` instead of `ReplaceAll` in the examples, the results don't seem so odd.

Comment: @Simon Probably you are right. But how to prevent applying attributes?

Comment: Mr Wizard, you used this property of Orderless in a nice answer of yours, that I think I bountied.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I'm not sure it is possible other than blocking the attribute. Probably you shouldn't use `Orderless` on symbols where you care about the ordering. You could, but I don't think it's a good habit, try to make the "first thing tried" be the one you want. In this case you could do it by using `{f[a], f[a + b]} /. HoldPattern[f[HoldPattern[x_] + y_.]] :> p[x, y]`

Comment: `Optional[...]` is sorted before `Pattern[...]`, but after `HoldPattern[...]`

Comment: @Rojo Interesting idea, thank you. In this particular case this solution looks reliable because it is based on documented *canonical order*.

Comment: @Rojo I am familiar with the basic effect of Orderless on pattern matching as you know; what I am not sure about is the order in which possibilities are themselves checked.  Your variation to match this particular order is clever; thanks for posting it.