# More general pattern fails to match everything the more specific pattern does.

Tags: pattern-matching

When I input this:

```
MatchQ[x*SF[a,b] + y*SF[c,d], Plus[Times[x,SF[a,b]],Times[y,SF[c,d]]]]
```

I get "True" as expected. But If I change it to:

```
MatchQ[x*SF[a,b] + y*SF[c,d], Plus[Times[_,SF[_,_]],Times[_,SF[_,_]]]]
```

Which ought to be more general, it returns false.

Why does this happen? I think it's evaluate the Plus, and return a pattern like Times[2,*,SF[*,_]]. But how do I make it stop doing that?

My goal is to Match the pattern for expressions like x*SF[a,b] + y*SF[c,d] + z*SF[e,f] ... 
So what do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Try `MatchQ[x*SF[a, b] + y*SF[c, d], 
 Plus[Times[x1_, SF[x2_, x3_]], Times[x4_, SF[x5_, x6_]]]]`.

Comment: Yeah,but I couldn't generalize that to make a it work for any amount of summands.

Answer (score 9):

You need to realize that pattern expressions evaluate just like any other in *Mathematica*.  Let's look at how this plays out for each pattern you gave:

```
Plus[Times[x, SF[a, b]], Times[y, SF[c, d]]]

Plus[Times[_, SF[_, _]], Times[_, SF[_, _]]]
```

> ```
> x SF[a, b] + y SF[c, d]
>
> 2 _ SF[_, _]
> ```

Clearly they are not equivalent.  In this particular case you can use `HoldPattern` to prevent this unwanted "simplification" from taking place:

```
MatchQ[
  x*SF[a, b] + y*SF[c, d], 
  Plus[Times[_, SF[_, _]], Times[_, SF[_, _]]] // HoldPattern
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Be aware that due to the `Orderless` attribute (and others) of `Plus`, `Times`, etc., you may still encounter unexpected behavior, e.g.:

[Different behaviours of Default Argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25476/121)

Comment: don't you think that the first argument to Times _ is to greedy and should be changed to a __ instead?

Comment: @Stefan I suppose it depends on what you expect it to match but perhaps I don't understand your concern.

Comment: if you use _, this is in that specific case the whole expression x,SF[a,b]],Times[y,SF[c,d], since _ is greedy like its regex equivalent *. If you use __ instead it is less greedy (like +?) and the expressions get evaluated correctly...

Comment: @Stefan I'm afraid I don't understand.  The parts I expect to correspond appear to, in e.g. `Replace[
 x*SF[a, b] + y*SF[c, d],
 q : Plus[r : Times[s : _, t : SF[_, _]], Times[_, SF[_, _]]] :> {q, r, s, t}
 ]` -- is a part of this pattern (q, r, s, t) is not as you expect?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No. Your answer is brilliant, but what I tried to say (see my answer) is, if you change the pattern in Times from '\_' to '__' it matches. Even with your Replacement code.

Comment: @Anon You're welcome.  Also take a look at the function `Verbatim` which while not applicable here (that I can see) is also important for making certain patterns work as desired.

Comment: sorry the double underscore is hard to display in comments...

Comment: @Stefan NFA - "National Fibromyalgia Association?" :o)  It works because the named patterns prevent the automatic simplification that breaks the original code.  (Wrap code in back-ticks in comments; double back-ticks of necessary.)

Comment: :))...luv it!...the name patterns prevent....let me think about that for a while...

Answer (score 0):

I always struggle with the pattern matching rules as well.

The first thing that is suspicious to me is the greedy `_` in your `Times` expression.

`_`, just like its regex counterpart `*`, is greedy and will match everything. But, if you change that one to `__` (regex `+` or even better `+?`) your matching succeeds.

```
MatchQ[x*SF[a, b] + y*SF[c, d], Plus[Times[__, SF[_, _]], Times[_, SF[_, _]]]]

(* Out: True *)
```

Comment: the more i look at it, the more doubtful my answer seems to me...the best would be maybe to capture the groups if this really matches the expression at all....

Comment: I don't think the original issue has anything to do with greedy patterns but rather automatic "simplification", which you (partly) avoid here due to use of *both* `_` and `__` -- however, if you change both `Times` expressions to use `__`: `Plus[Times[__, SF[_, _]], Times[__, SF[_, _]]]` it will evaluate to `2 __ SF[_, _]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Yes exactly. This is the point, where it gets weird to me. And that's why I expressed doubts about my answer...but it works; that you've to agree with. Even with your Replace expression above...I'm confused.

Comment: I imagine we are talking past each other and I apologize for that.  I'm merely trying to point out that the original pattern is analogous to `Times["x", "other"] + Times["x", "other"]` evaluating to `2 "other" "x"` and your change is analogous to `Times["y", "other"] + Times["x", "other"]` remaining separate terms. (`"other" "x" + "other" "y"`)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You don't have to apologise. It is the fault of the"National Fibromyalgia Association" and her little sister the "non deterministic finite automata". Puzzling creatures... :). Cheers. Always a pleasure to me.