# Selecting terms from a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra

There are similar questions to this on the forum but none fit the purpose here:

I would like to extract certain elements of a matrix depending on whether a factor is present
or not, and create another matrix of the same size with those elements and zeros everywhere else. For example, given

\begin{equation}
\left [
\begin{array}{c c}
a x & b x^2 \\
c y & d y^2
\end{array}
\right ]
\end{equation}

I would like to create a new matrix with just the elements that have $x^2$ 
as a member and zeros everywhere else.

\begin{equation}
\left [
\begin{array}{c c}
0   & b x^2 \\
0   & 0
\end{array}
\right ]
\end{equation}

I've tried variants of things like this but can't get it to work

```
SIGMA = {{ a x , b x^2},{c y , d y^2}};

SIGMAx2 = Select[SIGMA , MemberQ[#, x^2] &];
```

Answer (score 12):

Using `Replace` (assuming you only want to replace on level 2, as you mention "matrix"):

**Using `Except`**

*My first version*
(I kept this version to point out the usage/impact of [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Orderless.html))

```
Replace[SIGMA, Except[HoldPattern[___ x^2 ___]] -> 0, {2}]
```

> `{{0, b x^2}, {0, 0}}`

*Improved version, thanks to Leonid*

```
Replace[SIGMA, Except[___ x^2] -> 0, {2}]
```

as he explains below, this can be done since [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Times.html) is [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Orderless.html).

**Version using `FreeQ`**

Thanks to @ssch, we have a similar version, which is more general:

```
Replace[SIGMA, a_ /; FreeQ[a, x^2] -> 0, {2}]
```

Comment: (it should be fine now, I forgot the `HoldPattern`. Please let me know if it isn't)

Comment: +1. Note that `Times` is `Orderless`, therefore you don't need two blanks. This in turn allows to ditch `HoldPattern`, so that you could just use: `Replace[SIGMA, Except[___ x^2 ] -> 0, {2}]`.

Comment: ah, I had it that way in the beginning - then I added the second blank (obviously not thinking of `Orderless`) which screwed things up (I looked at `Trace` and couldn't make sense of it). Introducing `HoldPattern` solved it then (with the 2 blanks) (hence my first commend above). Thanks for pointing that out, @LeonidShifrin

Comment: No problem at all. This is a minor issue anyway.

Comment: Well, I was looking at something like: `{MatchQ[ x^2 c y, HoldPattern[___ x^2 ___]], 
 MatchQ[ x^2 c y, ___ x^2 ___], MatchQ[ x^2 c y, a___ x^2 b___]}`, and couldn't properly make sense of it (2nd vs 3rd), but now it makes sense (looking at `Trace`). And as `Except` doesn't allow named patterns, I chose to use `HoldPattern`.

Comment: Yes, pattern evaluation is a known issue, can be quite annoying. I seem to remember it being discussed here on SE more than once, but the one I found now is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27437/more-general-pattern-fails-to-match-everything-the-more-specific-pattern-does).

Comment: To work for more than Times you can use `Replace[m, a_ /; FreeQ[a, x^2] -> 0, {2}]`

Comment: @ssch: you want to post that as seperate answer, or shall I include in mine?

Comment: @PinguinDirk go ahead and put it in yours, I made a comment because I found it so similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very Useful indeed.

Answer (score 5):

For polynomials:

```
x^2 Coefficient[SIGMA, x, 2]
```

> ```
> {{0, b x^2}, {0, 0}}
> ```

$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & b x^2 \\
 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]$

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
Map[
    If[Length@Cases[#, x^2, Infinity] > 0, #, 0] &,
    SIGMA,
    {2}]
```

> ```
> {{0, b x^2}, {0, 0}}
> ```

This solution will work with more complex patterns than `Times` too.

Comment: It would be shorter to use `FreeQ` as by default that function uses a *levelspec* of `{0, Infinity}`:  `Map[If[FreeQ[#, x^2], 0, #] &, SIGMA, {2}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard of course, not many solutions would be worse than this :P I just was to hasty and then had a bus. After that, the battle was over :P

Comment: Kuba the basic idea is sound, though `Replace` is a bit cleaner.  I'd personally like to see you include the `FreeQ` form in your answer; I think you'd have arrived at it too given a bit more time to think about it.

Answer (score 3):

```
SIGMAx2 = Map[If[MemberQ[#, x^2, Infinity], #, 0] &, SIGMA, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{0, b x^2}, {0, 0}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list as `A`

```
 Table[If[(SameQ[A[[i, j]], #]) & /@ Cases[A, _*x^2, Infinity] /. 
       List -> Or, A[[i, j]], 0], {i, Length[A]}, {j, 1, Length[A[[i]]]}]
```

> {{0, b x^2}, {0, 0}}

In case you have more terms matching criteria than it will work as well,

```
A = {{a x, b x^2}, {c y x^2, d y^2}};
```

> {{0,b x^2},{c x^2 y,0}}