# FreeQ and arguments of Hypergeometric2F1

Tags: pattern-matching, special-functions

I was trying to use `FreeQ` to test for the presence of `Hypergeometric2F1` functions in my expressions. I encountered the following strange behaviour relating to the use of blanks `_` as arguments of `Hypergeometric2F1` in the pattern to be tested for.

```
FreeQ[Hypergeometric2F1[a1, a2, b1, x], Hypergeometric2F1[a1, a2, _, _]]
(*False*)
```

as it should be, but

```
FreeQ[Hypergeometric2F1[a1, a2, b1, x], Hypergeometric2F1[_, _, _, _]]
(*True*)
```

I'd be grateful if someone could educate me what's going on here. I use version 9.0 on Linux x86 (64-bit).

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: [(27437)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27437/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you run into unexpected results with pattern matching you need to consider how the pattern object itself evaluates.  For example consider these:

```
Plus[__]
Plus[_, _]
Times[_, _]
```

> ```
> __
>
> 2 _
>
> _^2
> ```

And now your pattern:

```
Hypergeometric2F1[_, _, _, _]
```

> ```
> (1 - _)^-_
> ```

To prevent this evaluation you can use either [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html) or [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim.html):

```
FreeQ[Hypergeometric2F1[a1, a2, b1, x], HoldPattern @ Hypergeometric2F1[_, _, _, _]]

FreeQ[Hypergeometric2F1[a1, a2, b1, x], Verbatim[Hypergeometric2F1][_, _, _, _]]
```

> ```
> False
>
> False
> ```

Recommended reading:

- [How to match a pattern with a pattern?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2778/121)
- [Pattern matching a pattern with patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17892/121)
- [Pattern matching on Orderless functions inside Hold](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30152/121)

Comment: Thanks, Mr.Wizard, also for the pointers to further reading!