# Matching (y/x)^u terms wherever the appear in an expression

Tags: pattern-matching

Mathematica keeps rewriting expressions, so it is hard to figure what pattern to use.

I am trying to replace all occurrences of $\frac{y}{x}$ by $t$, but Mathematica re-writes $\frac{1}{\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}$ to $\frac{x}{y}$ so pattern `y/x` fails sometimes depending on if it is in the numerator or denominator.

So switched to using at `FullForm` and checking for all combinations. But that also does not work, and I am sure I will miss some cases.

Here is an example

```
ClearAll[t, x, y]
expr = (y/x)^2;
FullForm[expr]
```

Gives

```
 Times[Power[x,-2], Power[y,2]]
```

So why does the below not match?

```
 expr/.Times[Power[x,-(any0_.)], Power[y,any0_.]] :>  t^any0
```

I am literally writing the same exact full form! But I changed the power to be anything. So in this case `any0_.` should match the `2`, right? But it does not:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It turned out removing the minus sign before `any0` above made it work, but I had to give the other power a different pattern name

```
   expr/.Times[Power[x, any0_.], Power[y, any1_.]] :>  t^any0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But that is not what I want. It should be $t^2$, I want the same pattern/power on both, but one with a minus sign to match. It looks like a when there is a minus sign there is a problem.

The main problem is really this: How do I change all `(y/x)`s anywhere in the expression to `t` so `(y/x)^3` will change to `t^3` as example?

The problem is also that Mathematica rewrites the expression internally so it is hard to know what pattern to use. What I am looking at is not what it is internally.

I even used the excellent [function by Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/using-cases-and-when-to-make-input-a-list-or-not):

```
getPatterns[expr_, pat_] := Last@Reap[expr /. a : pat :> Sow[a], _, Sequence @@ #2 &];
getPatterns[(y/x)^2, (y/x)^any_.]
```

But that did not pick this due to the re-writing.

```
 {}
```

I can't use `HoldForm` either on these things. Any idea how to do this which will work all the time?

Examples to test with

---

```
expr = (1 + 2 (y^2/x^2))/(2 (y/x))
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This should be transformed to $\frac{1+ 2 t^2}{2 t}$

```
 expr = y/x + Sqrt[1 + (y/x)^2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It should be transformed to $t+\sqrt{1+t^2}$

**Note:** It is *not* required that the pattern transforms things like `y^4/x^3` to `y t^3`. It can be assumed that `y/x` always shows with same power. But if the transformation can handle this general case, it will be even better, but not required.

Comment: What about e.g. `x^3/y^5`? Should it be left unchanged, replaced by `1/(t^3 y^2)` or by `1/(t^5 x^2)`?

Comment: @jkuczm This is meant as algebraic transformation, so yes, `x^3/y^5` should become `(1/t^3 y^2)`  but for now, this is _not_ required, as I make sure I enter the expression with terms as  `(y/x)^n` only. i.e. the expression will contain only terms of `(y/x)` of some powers.  I am keeping it simple. But if the code will also support the general case you showed, I will not complain ofcourse :)

Comment: What is your intent behind `HoldForm` in these examples?  As I attempted to illustrate in my answer that substantially changes the problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard oh, I just used `HoldForm` for illustration of what the input look like on the screen. Nothing more. Else mathematica will re-write it and becomes hard to see the `y/x` pattern. I do not use `HoldForm` at all in the code. Will remove `HoldForm` now so not be confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution: replace `y` with `t x`, and if there are any cases of `t x` hanging around with the `x` not cancelling, replace them with `y`.

```
(expression /. {y -> t x}) /. t x -> y
```

Testing it on some examples:

```
((1 + 2 (y^2/x^2))/(2 (y/x)) /. {y -> t x}) /. t x -> y
(y/5 /. {y -> t x}) /. t x -> y
(x/y /. {y -> t x}) /. t x -> y
(y/x + Sqrt[1 + (y/x)^2] /. {y -> t x}) /. t x -> y
```

> (1 + 2 t^2)/(2 t)
>
> y/5
>
> 1/t
>
> t + Sqrt[1 + t^2]

I would imagine that this is unlikely to be very robust. But I haven't tested on any convoluted examples.

Edit: To deal with the `x`s left at the end, just replace them all with `y/t`

```
r[expr_] := expr /. {y -> t x} /. {t x -> y} /. {x -> y/t}
```

Then, in addition to the above examples, we get

```
r[(y/x)*y]
r[y^4/x^3]
```

> t y
>
> t^3 y

Comment: Although this works so far, it has some strange side effect. For example, I expected `(y/x)*y` to be transformed to `t y` right? But it changes it to `t^2 x`.  Which is still correct, but a little unexpected. But that is not a big problem for me, as the input I have all contains `(y/x)` only terms and this case will not show up for what I need this for.

Comment: @Nasser See my edit. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, thanks , this looks good.

Comment: FWIW you do not strictly need the parentheses here as `/.` automatically groups this way.  `expr /. y -> t x /. t x -> y /. x -> y/t` should work the same.  If you like including explicit grouping of course that is your prerogative. Nice method, by the way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for that. Re: parentheses... Yes, I have parenthesis paranoia (parenthenoia?), so I tend to put them in where they're not really needed. I've removed them now.

Answer (score 10):

At least one of the problems you are encountering is that `-2` and `-x` *do not* share the same structure:

```
{-2, -x} // FullForm
```

> ```
> List[-2, Times[-1, x]]
> ```

You can not destructure `-2` using patterns.  You can check numerically however:

```
(y/x)^2 /. x^a_. y^b_. /; b == -a :> t^b
```

> ```
> t^2
> ```

Remember also that a matched expression is not further replaced, so you may need [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html).  Applied to your examples:

```
(1 + 2 (y^2/x^2))/(2 (y/x)) //. x^a_. y^b_. /; b == -a :> t^b

y/x + Sqrt[1 + (y/x)^2] //. x^a_. y^b_. /; b == -a :> t^b
```

> ```
> (1 + 2 t^2)/(2 t)
>
> t + Sqrt[1 + t^2]
> ```

---

A second potential problem is operating on a manually entered held form such as `HoldForm[(1 + 2 (y^2/x^2))/(2 (y/x))]` without realizing that this can have a *very different* internal form compared to an evaluated expression.  Compare:

```
foo = HoldForm[(1 + 2 (y^2/x^2))/(2 (y/x))];
bar = HoldForm @@ {(1 + 2 (y^2/x^2))/(2 (y/x))};

foo // TreeForm
bar // TreeForm
```

[image]

[image]

---

I would be remiss not to mention that general algebraic manipulation should not be done with pattern matching if at all avoidable.  See for example [Replacing composite variables by a single variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3463/121#3465) and be aware of:

- [Can I simplify an expression into form which uses my own definitions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/121)

---

Other things to be aware of:

- [More general pattern fails to match everything the more specific pattern does.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27437/121)
- [Pattern matching on Orderless functions inside Hold](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30152/121)

Answer (score 2):

I know, this is not really the answer to your question. But at least in this specific problem, this helps:

```
expr /. {y -> t x}
```

Next try:

```
r = {
   Times[z___, Power[x, k_], Power[y, l_], w___] :> If[k == -l,
     Times[z, Power[t, l], w],
     Times[z, Power[x, k], Power[y, l], w]
     ],
   Times[z___, x, Power[y, -1], w___] :> Times[z, 1/t, w],
   Times[z___, Power[x, -1], y, w___] :> Times[z, t, w]
   };

x/y //. r
y^2/x^2 //. r
y^3/x^2 //. r
(1 + 2 (y^2/x^2))/(2 (y/x)) //. r
y/x + Sqrt[1 + (y/x)^2] //. r

(* 1/t *)
(* t^2 *)
(* y^3/x^2 *)
(* (1 + 2 t^2)/(2 t) *)
(* t + Sqrt[1 + t^2] *)
```

The second branch of the `If` statement can be used to further elaborate on the third example. But admittedly, this is starting to get complicated...

Comment: Thanks, but this does not really do it. I need to first check that the `y/x` actually is there ! Else, I will be replacing    `y/5` by `t x/5` which makes no sense. This is meant to only replace `y/x` if it exists !

Comment: I know... This is a really interesting problem that I also stumpled upon several times.

Comment: no problem. This is hard, because mathematica re-writes expression. so what one is looking at, is not the same as what is used internally. So patterns sometimes do not work because of this.

Comment: @Nasser You could use this function as only transformation function of `Simplify`: `Simplify[{(a y)/(b x), x/y, y^2/x^2, y^5/x^3, a x y}, TransformationFunctions -> {# /. y -> t x &}] (* {(a t)/b, 1/t, t^2, t^5 x^2, a x y} *)`. If this will be to eager and replace some instance we don't want to be replaced, one could also play with `ComplexityFunction` to prevent it.

Comment: As an extension to @HenrikSchumacher's first answer, you could try `(expression /. {y -> t x}) /. t x -> y`. It appears to work for the test case at the end of the question (returns the required expression in `t`), `y/5` (which remains unaltered), and `x/y` (returns `1/t`). Very probably not robust, I would guess, but nice and simple if it works.

Comment: Thanks for trying. But I can't get your code to do the transformation on the two examples I showed.

Comment: @aardvark2012 thanks! Your code actually worked on the two examples I have ! Will try it on more examples. Feel free to post it as answer.