# How to make a Flat function return x when evaluated as f[x]?

Tags: pattern-matching, attributes

With `SetAttributes[f, Flat]`, `f[a_]` can get matched to `f` of any number arguments. How can I make it that calling it with exactly one argument `f[x]` returns `x`?

I'm trying to have an operation just like `NonCommutativeMultiply` but without the "Possible Issues" it has. It is important to me that if the result of some simplification is a "product" of one term it is no longer treated as such.

I especially want to avoid infinite loops like

```
f[a_] := a
f[a__] /; AnyTrue[{a}, FreeQ[_Symbol]] := "free"
f[a, a]
```

> $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >>

Comment: use `SetAttributes[f, Flat]` _**after**_ `f[a_] := a`?

Comment: closely related/possible duplicate: [SetAttributes: Why the order dependence?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/304/125)