# Clear complains that a subscripted variable is not a symbol or a string?

Tags: syntax, variable-definitions, clear

Here's a small listing where I've used <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to typeset `θ` in the notebook:

```
Clear[ f, θ, Subscript[x, r] ]
Subscript[x, r] := 3
f[θ_] := Subscript[x, r] Cos[θ]

Plot[f[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}]
```

(in my notebook this looked like $x_r$, not `Subscript[x, r]` for example).

This produces a message from `Clear` of the form:

```
Clear::ssym : x_r is not a symbol or a string
```

What is curious is that I appear to be able to assign to this variable $x_r$ without any trouble, yet it is apparently treated differently than my other symbols `f` and `θ`.

How exactly does Mathematica define a symbol.  Why can I use $x_r$ like a variable, yet it does not have this symbol characterization?

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with `DownValue`, `OwnValue` and so on it is worth reading this post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues in addition to the answers below.

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/WEXBolRa15Y/discussion

Comment: Related: [(1004)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1004/121)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your code reveals exactly why `Clear` complains: `Subscript[x, r]` is not a `Symbol` nor a `String`. When you assign a [value to it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/52), you're setting a `DownValue` not an `OwnValue`; in other words, you're setting the value of a function not a variable. To use $x_r$ as a symbol, use the [`` Notation` ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html) package's function, `Symbolize`. I'd recommend using it from the palette directly, as it has all of the intricacies already set up for you.

Comment: ...and you can use `ClearNotations` to clear your `Symbolize`d symbols.

Comment: rcollyer wrote: "Subscript[x, r] is not a Symbol nor a String" ........... That rather evades the point. Why should `Clear` be artificially restricted to operate on Symbols or Strings? I cannot think of any reason why Clear[$x_1$] should not be able to work. In my view, this is a blatant user-interface failing of Mma, and one that has been unnecessarily unresolved for over 20 years.

Comment: @wolfies I find that you frustrate me. It is apparent that you either did not read the rest of the text I wrote or deliberately ignored it so that you could express your frustration. `Unset` works, but it is unclear what `Clear` would operate on, `Subscript`, `x`, `1`? What about the case where both arguments to `Subscript` are symbols, what should happen then? Without ``Notation` ``, `Subset[x,1]` is _not_ atomic! So, if you have a better way, submit an answer.

Comment: As you are perfectly aware, `Unset[$x_1$]` works ... in fact, it is required, since `Clear` fails to provide a uniform clearing interface. And since `Unset` does the job, there is plainly no inherent reason that `Clear` cannot be made to operate in the same manner. `Clear` doesn't have to be atomic. That _is_ the point. As for your 'frustrations' ... ?

Answer (score 28):

As the error message indicates [`Clear`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clear.html) does not work that way.  There are several assignment forms that automatically create a definition to something other than a raw symbol:

```
x[5] = 1;
Subscript[x, 1] = 2;
x /: Subscript[x, 2] = 3;
N[x] = 3.14159;

DownValues[x]
DownValues[Subscript]
UpValues[x]
NValues[x]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[x[5]] :> 1}
>
> {HoldPattern[Subscript[x, 1]] :> 2}
>
> {HoldPattern[Subscript[x, 2]] :> 3}
>
> {HoldPattern[N[x, {MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision}]] :> 3.14159}
> ```

(See documentation for: [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html), [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpValues.html). `NValues` is not directly documented.)

You cannot clear any of these forms in the fashion you attempted:

```
(* Failure

Clear[ x[5] ]
Clear[ Subscript[x, 1] ]
Clear[ Subscript[x, 2] ]
Clear[ N[x] ]

*)
```

You can clear some of them with [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unset.html) (short form `=.`):

```
x[5] =.
Subscript[x, 1] =.
N[x]  =.
```

`Unset[Subscript[x, 2]]` does not work because it was created with [`TagSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSet.html) (`/:`), and for that you need [`TagUnset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagUnset.html):

```
x /: Subscript[x, 2] =.
```

Comment: I thought about mentioning `Unset`, but didn't. So, you get the +1.

Comment: What is NValues? I haven't seen it elsewhere.

Comment: @IonSme `NValues` gives the values explicitly assigned to `N[x]` for symbol `x`.  This is like an UpValue but is specific to `N` and happens automatically without use of `^=`.

Answer (score 16):

You get that error because Mathematica does not recognize $x_r$ as a symbol. To instruct it to treat symbols with subscripts also as symbols, you'll need to use the `` Notations` `` package like so:

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
```

Now you should have no problems in clearing your subscripted symbol.

Answer (score 8):

That is because the value is set to a DownValue of Subscript..

```
DownValues[Subscript]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to clear all subscript variables, similarly to `Clear["Global'*"]` (the `'` should be a backtick) I have always used the following with good results:

```
Clear["Subscript"]
```

Which seems to clear all variables of the form:

```
Subscript[r,1]
```

Comment: It's a nice idea, but it only works with definitions that are attached to the Symbol `Subscript`.  See my answer for examples of other definitions.