# Can we use letter with a subscript as a variable in Mathematica?

Tags: custom-notation

I tried

```
Subscript[a, 0] = 1
(* 1 *)

Clear[Subscript[a, 0]]
```

> ```
>        During evaluation of Clear::ssym: Subscript[a, 0] is not a symbol or a string. >>
> ```

```
Clear[a]
Subscript[a, 0]
(* 1 *)
```

Any idea?

Comment: This probably should have been marked as a duplicate question on stackoverflow. See [[1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4253883/421225)] (and maybe [[2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5481216/421225)])
Should we also migrate the other post and/or merge? Or are we happy with the question being covered on both sites? Of course, [@Spartacus' answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1005/34) covers most variations of this question. +1!

Comment: This is contained in Mr. Wizard's answer below, but the short and sweet of it that does exactly what I want is: Type your variable name, e.g. "a", then CTRL and - to type your subscript. You can assign a value using ":=", but to remove the assignment the Clear command won't work, but Unset command will work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes you can, with limitations.

You have at least three different ways to make an assignment to a subscripted symbol a<sub>0</sub> :

1. make a rule for `Subscript`
2. make a rule for `a`
3. "symbolize" a<sub>0</sub> using the Notation package/palette

In each case below, when I write e.g. `Subscript[a, 1]` this can also be entered as a<sub>1</sub> by typing <kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> then <kbd>1</kbd>.

When you write:

```
Subscript[a, 1] = "dog";
```

You make an assignment to `Subscript`:

```
DownValues[Subscript]
```

> {HoldPattern[a<sub>1</sub>] :> "dog"}

You make a rule for `a` by using `TagSet`:

```
a /: Subscript[a, 2] = "cat";

UpValues[a]
```

> {HoldPattern[a<sub>2</sub>] :> "cat"}

If you use the Notation palette you mess with underlying Box forms behind the scenes, allowing for assignment to `OwnValues`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Each of these can be cleared with either `Unset` or `TagUnset`:

```
Subscript[a, 1] =.

a /: Subscript[a, 2] =.
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It's worth noting that you can directly type a shortcut for subscripts, but I don't know how to show this here. Namely:
    a<sub>3</sub> = "lion";
where "<sub>3</sub> should be an actual subscript, typed in the Mathematica Front End by first typing Ctrl _ .

Comment: is it good MMA form to convert subscript as quickly as possible to something like `a5` and then at the last step for output output the result with a subscript, so do the majority of manipulations with identifiers like `a5`?

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G That would work but usually it is better to use e.g. `a[5]` which makes conversion in either direction much simpler and faster.  However there are places (like `Module`) that actual Symbols are needed.  Also, I haven't looked at the internals of the Notation palette in some years but I seem to recall that the use of `Symbolize` is performing this kind of translation itself, such that Symbols are used in place of Subscripts during computation, then formatted again as Subscripts for output, so look at that before you "reinvent the wheel" as it were.

Comment: Is there any way that we could clear by `ClearAll["Global*"]`?

Comment: @H.R. If you use the `TagSet` method the rule is attached to e.g. `a`, and if `a` is in the Global context `ClearAll["Global*"]` will clear that rule.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard (per your mention of not having looked at the ``Notation` `` internals in a while) all it does is coerce the boxes to a string representation (in the case of `Subscripts` this is `x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]*`) and then applies `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression` in the way one would expect. This means you can easily clear all such variables via `Clear@"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]*"`.

Answer (score 12):

You can also do this:

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
```

If you want to, you can import the Notation package first, then use the Symbolize function, so you don't have to use the ParsedBoxWrapper function, and just enter `_,(ctrl+_),_`. What this does, is set a pattern matching a subscripted character as a symbol. Mathematica will then treat expressions matching this form as a single variable.

This doesn't seem to affect functions that use subscripts in their definition such as the partial differential function.

Comment: For what it's worth this is mentioned as point #3 in my answer, then illustrated further down.

Comment: I saw, and it was very useful. I just thought I would expand it so that any subscripted pattern would be interpreted as a symbol.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Okay +1 :-)

Comment: (+1) Nicely done! :) I was looking for this since the day I started using *Mathematica*! :)

Comment: Works like a charm. However it kind of breaks calls to TraditionalForm and TeXForm.