# How to define a vector with automatically added symbolic elements with subscripts

Tags: variable-definitions, symbols, custom-notation

I want to define a vector lets say **k** containing elements Symbolize[Subscript[*k*, 1]], *k2*, *k3* ...  etc. When I define lets say *k4* . I want the symbol automatically added to vector k. Something like below but not working at all.

```
k /: {k, Symbolize[
 ParsedBoxWrapper[
 SubscriptBox[
 StyleBox["v", FontFamily -> "Courier New", FontWeight -> "Plain", 
   FontSlant -> "Italic"], "_"]]]} := 
AppendTo[k, Subscript[v, _]];
```

My Question is;

1) How can I symbolically define elements (with sub scripts) automatically added to a vector.

2) If I assign values to symbols, How can I get elements values only and symbols only.

**EDIT 1**

```
Symbolize[Subscript[k, _]]
```

Command Symbolizes all subscripts of **k**  e.g. *k1* (`Subscript[k, 1]`), *k2* (`Subscript[k, 2]`) etc. This is fine. What I want is collect *k1, k2 k3* in a set (List) **k** with out additional commands or additional functions. Just as soon as sybolize sub scripted ones it should add it self to set k (sort of pattern maching as in `Subscript[k, _]`). When I call k it should give me the list {*k1, k2, k3*}. @Mr. Wizards answer gives the list but as calling function `ksym`. Sort of what I need but not exactly. @halirutan answer is also interesting but I don' t want to define additional functions or operators (may be as minimum as possible).

**EDIT 2**

Its sort of bag or set; no order is required,  only *k1,k3* can be given and *k2* can be missing.

**EDIT 3**

```
<< Notation`
(*below line symbolizes all subscripted k_]*)
Symbolize[ ParsedBoxWrapper[
   SubscriptBox["k", "_"]]]
```

somewhere here I need additional code that all *k*_ are added to k once its been defined. For example:

```
{Subscript[k, 1], Subscript[k, 2], Subscript[k, 3]} = {1, 2, 3}
```

after that when I ask k it should give me `{Subscript[k, 1], Subscript[k, 2], Subscript[k, 3]}` as @Mr.Wizard suggested `ksym[] := HoldForm @@@ UpValues[k][[All, 1]]` and for values `kval[] := UpValues[k][[All, 2]]` should work. But, what I' m missing in @Mr.Wizard  example is that one needs to define symbols as;

```
k /: Subscript[k, 1] = "val1";
k /: Subscript[k, 2] = "val2";
k /: Subscript[k, 3] = "val3";
```

what I need is once I write `{Subscript[k, 1], Subscript[k, 2], 
   Subscript[k, 3]} = {1, 2, 
   3}` I should be able to get k vector and `{Subscript[k, 1], 
   Subscript[k, 2], Subscript[k, 3]}` is appended automatically to k.

Comment: I think I don't really understand your second question. Could you write a bit more what you mean exactly?

Comment: @halirutan Thank  you for your answer. Please see the edit as well as Mr. Wizards answer. It's very close to what I asked for.

Comment: Have you thought about what should happen if you define $k_1$ and $k_3$, but not $k_2$? Does the resulting list only contain $\{k_1, k_3\}$ or is there supposed to be some placeholder for $k_2$? Can't really answer your question if that isn't defined first.

Comment: @Jens Its sort of bag or set neither order is required nor k1,k2,k3, so k2 can be missing.

Comment: s.s.o, you haven't responding to my question in the comments below my answer.  I'd still like to help further if I can.  You may be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3067/121), but I think a different syntax is a better way to approach the problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, currently I'm very busy. I'll reply as soon as I have more time. I should have informed you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method #1

If you define each Subscript using `TagSet`<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/379/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1005/121)</sup> the value will be associated with the Symbol, e.g. `k`:

```
k /: Subscript[k, 1] = "val1";
k /: Subscript[k, 2] = "val2";
k /: Subscript[k, 3] = "val3";
```

You could then use definitions such as:

```
kval[] := UpValues[k][[All, 2]]

ksym[] := HoldForm @@@ UpValues[k][[All, 1]]
```

These will always be up to date as they are dynamically generated:

```
kval[]
```

> {"val1", "val2", "val3"}

```
ksym[]
```

> {k<sub>1</sub>, k<sub>2</sub>, k<sub>3</sub>}

Each "symbol" name is wrapped in `HoldForm` to prevent evaluation; `ReleaseHold` may be used to trigger it.

These definitions assume that no other `UpValues` for `k` are generated but if there are that can be addressed with pattern matching at the expense of speed.

---

### Method #2

Following your update **EDIT 3** here is another approach you might consider.  Start by setting `HoldFirst` on `Subscript` so that `k` may be used without forming an infinite recursion, then make a definition for `k` that extracts the matching rules from the `DownValues` list:

```
SetAttributes[Subscript, HoldFirst]

k := Cases[DownValues@Subscript, (_[x : Subscript[k, _]] :> _) :> Hold[x]]
```

Make some assignments and check `k`:

```
{Subscript[k, 1], Subscript[k, 2], Subscript[k, 3]} = {"a", "b", "c"}

k
```

> ```
> {Hold[Subscript[k, 1]], Hold[Subscript[k, 2]], Hold[Subscript[k, 3]]}
> ```

The subscripts are returned in held form, for further processing.  One can use `ReleaseHold` to recover the values:

```
k // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> {"a", "b", "c"}
> ```

Comment: @ Mr. Wizard your guess is wright :) Please see the edit 1 if it needs further clarification.

Comment: @s.s.o Could you explain for me in what way my proposal is lacking?  I see a problem with your specification in that it is not likely practical (though not entirely impossible) to have a single symbol `k` serve both purposes, so if your objection is to the use of a different symbol (`kval`, `ksym`) I'm not sure that can be fixed in a robust way.  Again if things like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1123/121) are acceptable more possibilities open, but I would not choose that here myself.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard please see the edit 3 if it needs further explanation.

Comment: @s.s.o please see my update and tell me if this does what you want, or if it is at least getting close.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard I think it's very close to what I asked for. I'll check it tonight. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't like the `Notation` stuff very much, I regard the question as very nice, because it offers some insight into the evaluation process.
When you bind `UpValues` to the symbol `k` and `k` has `DownValues` (because you want it to hold your list too), you have to make sure that `k` is not evaluated because otherwise the rule you gave as `UpValues` never kicks in.

One way to prevent this is to use an operator which holds its arguments anyway. One such an operator is `+=` which could be interpreted in your context as *append another `k_n` to the vector `k`*. To keep it as simple as possible, let's say I want to following notation:

```
k+=1
```

which means, append $k_1$ to the vector $k$. If $k$ has no value, create a new list and put $k_1$ as first element.

```
<< Notation`
k /: k += n_ := With[{sn = ToString[n]},
  If[! ValueQ[k], k = {}];
  Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["k", sn]]];
  AppendTo[k, 
   ToExpression["k\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]" <> sn]]
]
```

And now everything happens automatically.

```
Table[k += i, {i, 10}];
k
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]