# Print indexed (by subscript) variable name systematically

Tags: variable-definitions, printing

I have some variables : Subscript[S, 1], Subscript[S, 2]...etc.
But they are defined in a for loop like `For[g = 1, g < 4, g++, Subscript[S, g] = g];`
Later, I need to print each of the variable name, i.e `Subscript[S, 1], Subscript[S, 2]`...etc. But I can't find a systematic way to do this. `For[g = 1, g < 4, g++, Print[HoldForm@Subscript[S, g]]];` doesn't work because it prints `Subscript[S, g]` always.

Any idea?

Just look at the code:

```
For[g = 1, g < 4, g++, Subscript[S, g] = g];
Print[Subscript[S, 1]]
Print[Subscript[S, 2]]
Print[Subscript[S, 3]]
For[g = 1, g < 4, g++, Print[Subscript[S, g]]];
Print[HoldForm@Subscript[S, 1]]
Print[HoldForm@Subscript[S, 2]]
Print[HoldForm@Subscript[S, 3]]
For[g = 1, g < 4, g++, Print[HoldForm@Subscript[S, g]]];
For[g = 1, g < 4, g++, Subscript[S, g] =.];
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `Defer` and [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: You should use `Do[..., {g, 3}]` instead of `For[g = 1, g < 4, g++, ...];`. It's idiomatic, easier to read and maintain, and possibly faster. Or `Map`, if possible, or some other construct.

Comment: @ssch, using defer instead HoldForm@ still prints S_g.

Comment: Just HoldForm/Defer the `S` part: `Subscript[S, 3] = 4; g = 3; Subscript[Defer[S], g]`

Comment: You may benefit from this answer which adds automatically symbolic elements with subscript. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22376/how-to-define-a-vector-with-automatically-added-symbolic-elements-with-subscript

Comment: Related: [(7756)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121)

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

```
Table[Subscript[HoldForm @ S, i], {i, 3}]

Table[With[{i = i}, HoldForm @ Subscript[S, i]], {i, 3}]

Table[i /. x_ :> HoldForm @ Subscript[S, x], {i, 3}]
```

You could also use [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html) as ssch mentioned if you want to be able to use the output as input that evaluates.