# Recursion problem

Tags: recursion, system

I try to make designation

```
a = {Subscript[a,1], Subscript[a,2], Subscript[a,3]}
```

but receive mistake

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.

What`s the problem?

Comment: Don't use subscripts until you're an expert. A subscripted symbol isn't a symbol

Comment: @belisarius: Given *Mathematica*'s formatting palettes etc., users are actually lead into using that quite common mathematical notation, especially when it comes to vectors, matrices etc...

Comment: @Jinxed That's true, but it doesn't make the advice less valid. Subscripted variables should be usually avoided. If one really cannot live without them use the Notation package.

Comment: So what _is_ subscripted stuff used for (except typsetting, of course)? I've browsed around for links, but all I found was warnings for beginners never to use them or to use the Notation package.

Comment: It`s a little strange situation: it`s possible to Superscript (not the Power) but impossible to Subscript (not index). It`s not good. In any case. Many thanks for all. Where to find wish list for mma?

Comment: @SergeyFomin: You should contact Wolfram support for this. The more such notes they get, the more likely they will do something about that. I e.g. would appreciate to have such constructs automatically symbolized, since I really like to have formulas displayed in typeset form in order to better serve my users' needs.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Sure, but how should the aspiring *Mathematica*-user know about that behavior? It is hard to find even a mention in the documentation. As I wrote to Sergey: Why not automatically symbolize such constructs if entered in a typeset way? This would solve such problems, while leaving the option to actually use `Subscript` for advanced purposes and advanced users.

Comment: @Jinxed It's mentioned in our most popular [Mathematica Pitfalls question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users?s=1|1.0278). No substitute for documentation, I know, but Sergey has been on this site for over two and a half years.

Comment: A possible solution it to use Hold attributes; see: [(20195)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20195/121), [(22376)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22376/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is, that while assigning, the `a` in `Subscript[a,_]` is replaced by the whole list of subscripts, and so on and so on, until the recursion limit is reached: Subscripts are no symbols by themselves.

To avoid this, you can either use another variable to assign to (`b` e.g.), or define the subscripts as proper symbols:

```
Needs["Notation`"]

makesymbol[obj_]:=With[{},      
  If[NameQ@ToString@Unevaluated@obj,Remove@obj]; (* remove possibly existing symbol first *)
  Symbolize@ParsedBoxWrapper@ToBoxes@obj;]       (* then create the new symbol *)
```

With this function, you can create a symbol like so:

```
makesymbol[Subscript[a,1]]
```

*Mathematica* will now treat it the same as any other (simpler) symbol.

**For your case:**

*Be sure to put the formatted variables into the list here, not the `Subscript`-form:*

```
makesymbol /@ {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3]}
```

and then your assignment will work without problems.

Comment: makesymbol[Subscript[a,1]] doesn`t return any result, makesymbol /@ {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3]} return {Null,Null,Null}

Comment: @SergeyFomin It's not supposed to return a result. However, after executing the above commands you are now able to use the subscripted variables treated with it as real variables. Look at the FullForm of a_1 with the subscript entered using the keyboard (using ctrl + _ on my US International keyboard)

Comment: @SergeyFomin: Did my answer work out for you?

Answer (score 3):

My favorite approach when it's unavoidable to use such formatting is this simple trick:

```
a = {Subscript["a", 1], Subscript["a", 2], Subscript["a", 3]}

(* ==> {Subscript["a", 1], Subscript["a", 2], Subscript["a", 3]} *)
```

Just make the subscripted names into strings. You can then do things like `a[[1]]` or even `Subscript["a", 1] = 10` without getting in trouble. The quotation marks also remind you that you're dealing with something more subtle: The value in the last assignment is stored in `DownValues[Subscript]`. This is the big difference in using `Subscript` versus regular symbol names, and one should never forget it.

As usual, you can find most of this by searching the following giant Q&A: [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/245).