# Getting $RecursionLimit errors with FindRoot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

The first time I ran the cells the program was fine, then I started using FindRootPlot, but it didn't work well so I removed the line and went back to using FindRoot and it gave me some crawl errors that I don't quite understand
[image: This is the program working well]

[image: This is the same program but after I used the FindRootPlot]

Comment: Please copy and paste, or retype, Mathematica code into a question and indent it manually or using the use {} button. Then readers can directly copy and paste into a notebook. They *cannot* do this if you just insert images of code!

Answer (score 4):

I think the recursion behavior is due to the use of `Subscript`(See [77625](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77624/recursion-problem/77625#77625)).

To solve this problem:

1. Stop using subscripts for evaluations.
2. Use `Clear["Subscript", "x"]` to clean the definitions(which are cleaned by your `Quit`).