# Problem storing $x_j$ terms in variable x

Tags: core-language

This works:

```
Table[Subscript[x, j], {j, 1, 10}]
```

But this doesn't:

```
x = Table[Subscript[x, j], {j, 1, 10}]
```

Giving this warning:

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of Subscript[x, 1]. >>

Can someone explain why this happens?

Students can do this of course:

```
Clear[x,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10]
x={x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10};
```

But what's the easiest way (for students just starting to use Mathematica) to enter x1, x2, through x100 and store them in the variable x?

Comment: You are defining `x` in terms of `x`; hence the error. Use `Indexed[]` instead.

Comment: Or do `xs = Array[x, 100]`, which is how I would do it. If you insist on `Subscript`s, do `xs = Array[Subscript[x,#]&, 100]`

Comment: `Indexed` or simply `x[i]` for the win.

Comment: @J.M. Can you please give me a complete line of code for the Indexed command, storing the answer in a variable, so I am sure of what you are suggesting? Thanks.

Comment: Closely related: [(22376)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22376/121).  Also perhaps worth reading, including the various questions linked therein: [(6511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you can't define a symbol in terms of its own `DownValues` or in terms of `Subscript`s of itself, so these both give recursion errors:

```
ClearAll[x]
x = Table[x[n], {n, 5}]
ClearAll[x]
x = Table[Subscript[x, n], {n, 5}]
```

I would suggest either of these workarounds:

```
ClearAll[x]
x = Table[Symbol["x" <> IntegerString[n]], {n, 5}]
(* {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5} *)
```

or

```
ClearAll[x]
xlist = Table[x[n], {n, 5}]
(* {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]} *)
```

That last one of course would work with subscripts too, although we try to [discourage](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1005/9490) using subscripts for anything other than display formulas,

```
ClearAll[x]
xlist = Table[Subscript[x, n], {n, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'd like to thank you and your colleagues for some excellent help.

Comment: Jason, I marked this question as a duplicate.  Please let me know if you disagree with that action.  I noticed only after the final question here, though that is probably also a duplicate of others.