# How to create symbol whose name has subscript?

Tags: symbols

I can do

```
Symbol["foobar"]
```

to create a symbol `foobar`.  How to create a symbol $\theta_1$?

```
Symbol[Subscript[\[Theta], 1]]
```

doesn't work.

Comment: `Subscript[\[Theta], 1] = 20` works.

Comment: I know;  Do this fact help answer the question?  Or do you mean define the symbol by assigning a value?  How to create the symbol without having to assign it an arbitrary value at the same time?

Comment: I could create a symbol without assigning a value to it with `Subscript[\[Theta], 1]`. Beyond that I am unsure what you want to do with the symbol.

Comment: Have you seen this?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica

Comment: How about the `Notation` package?

Comment: Indexed also works

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although your question is stated clear, I'm still wondering whether you understood, that `Subscript[\[Theta], 1]` *is* not a symbol. It's a box-structure! Therefore, what you do when you assign it a value like

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

is, that you *don't* assign a value to some indexed variable `x`. No, you assign a value (a `DownValue`) to `Subscript`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's assume I can guess that you like to use some indexed variable in your code then you should consider to work with the `Notation` package as already pointed out in the comments.

You can, after loading the `Notation` package, define a symbol like pattern which you want to use for a indexed variable. So for instance

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, that the parameter is *`x` subscript `Blank[]`*!

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["x", "_"]]]
```

If you now look at `InputForm[Subscript[x, 1]]` you see, that the notation package transforms this into valid symbol-name only consisting of letters

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

At this point you could use `ToExpression` to define a vector

```
Table[ToExpression["Subscript[x, " <> ToString[i] <> "]"], {i, 10}]
```

and the moment you evaluate this you have your new variables

```
Names["x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]*"]
(*
{"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]1", 
"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]10", 
"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]2", 
"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]3", 
"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]4", 
"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]5", 
"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]6", 
"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]7", 
"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]8", 
"x\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]9"}
*)
```

Comment: Hi, halirutan. I tried your method. But `InputForm[Subscript[x, 1]]` doesn't give expected result. see http://pasteboard.co/a4QgrQ9ja.png

Comment: Because I assumed that `Subscript` is automatically transformed to its box-form. You need to input the subscript with `Ctrl+_`. Otherwise, it doesn't work. But it must have worked at some point, because I wouldn't have put it in a post without testing. This is really odd.

Comment: What's wrong with assigning value to a `Subscript`? I don't seem to run into unexpected behavior with it. Can you please give an example where assigning to `Subscript` gives wrong results? Maybe it is a performance disaster?

Comment: @Adobe Look at [this simple example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sabg7.png). Especially, pay attention to the error message. Do you truly believe, a newbie would know what he did wrong? The same happens with `With` and `Block`. So basically, you cannot use those variables in some local context.

Comment: @halirutan: You right, it doesn't work in local context, but with `Notation` [it works](http://i.imgur.com/thhhWlT.png). However, it breaks `TraditionalForm`.