# Integrated Solution Graphics

Tags: graphics

I want to draw this nonlinear differantial equation' graphic with other solving equation (in same graphic).

```
ϵ y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 0, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1/2

y^c = 1/(x + 
   1) - (1 + 2 x) E^(-(
    x/ϵ)) + ϵ {2/(x + 1)^2 Log[2/(
       x + 1)] + (1/2 - 2 Log[2]) E^(-(x/ϵ)) - 
     1/2 E^(-((2 x)/ϵ))}
```

I got nonlinear differantial equation' numerical solution with this form.

```
ϵ = 0.1;
functions = NDSolveValue[{ϵ y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 0, y[0] == 0, 
                          y[1] == 1/2}, {y, x}, {x, 0, 1}];

Plot[Evaluate@Through@functions@x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I hope the edited answer gives you the desired result. Check the documentation of [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html?q=Show) and [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html?q=Plot) for details.

Comment: Also note that curly braces are for lists [The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html) and that subscripted variables might not behave a you'd expect in *Mathematica*. Check [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) on how to make indexed objects and e.g. [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13782/18476).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ϵ = 0.1;

func = NDSolveValue[{ϵ y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 0, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1/2}, 
        y, {x, 0, 1}]

y2[x_] := 1/(x + 1) - (1 + 2 x) E^(-(x/ϵ)) + ϵ (2/(x + 1)^2 Log[2/(x + 1)] 
          + (1/2 - 2 Log[2]) E^(-(x/ϵ)) - 1/2 E^(-((2 x)/ϵ)))
```

You can display both functions inside one plot using

```
Plot[{func[x], y2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> [image]

or

```
p1 = Plot[func[x], {x, 0, 1}];
p2 = Plot[y2[x], {x, 0, 1}];
Show[p1, p2]
```

> [image]

Comment: @GenceDeveci What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Mathematica 9.0 ( "c" is not number it is only constant as a character)