# Converting the subscript of matrix name to a variable

Tags: matrix, variable-definitions, subscript

I want to change indices of matrix name during loop for creating different matrices. For example;

```
For[i=1,i=5,i++
   Ki={{i,2*i},{3*i,4*i}};   (* i subscript)
   ]

(* to generate K1, K2,....K5 *)
```

I need help on this.

Comment: `For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, K[i] = {{i, 2*i}, {3*i, 4*i}}]` will generate `K[1]`,`K[2]`,...

Comment: It's bad practice to use subscripts as variables - I'm sure we have a canonical answer somewhere, but https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13782/30771

Comment: Did the answer below answer your question? If so, please accept it by clicking the grey question mark to the left of the answer!

Answer (score 5):

For pedagogical purposes:

- In general, using `Subscript`s to define variables is a bad idea in *Mathematica*. In your problem, I suggest either using `k[n]` or defining a `List` `ks` where each element is one of your matrices.
- Avoid using capital letters when defining variables. All *Mathematica* built-ins start with capital letters; for instance, `K` is a reserved symbol in *Mathematica*, so using it might cause problems.
- There are syntax errors in your `For` loop. To make it do what you want, here would be the correct syntax:

  ```
  Clear[i, k]
  For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++
    , k[i] = {{i, 2*i}, {3*i, 4*i}}
   ]
  ```

However, in *Mathematica*, it is often [beneficial to avoid loops](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica). Here are a couple of alternatives to the method you've outlined.

- Use `Do`:

  ```
  Do[k[i] = {{i, 2*i}, {3*i, 4*i}}, {i, 1, 5}]
  ```
- Use a `Table` to construct a list of `k`'s. You can get parts of lists using `[[ <> ]]`:

  ```
  ks = Table[{{i, 2*i}, {3*i, 4*i}}, {i, 1, 5}];
  ks[[2]]
  (* {{2, 4}, {6, 8}} *)
  ```
- Use `Scan` in order to evaluate a function with side effects while avoiding any outputs.

  ```
  f[num_] := k[num] = {{num, 2*num}, {3*num, 4*num}}
  Scan[f, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
  ```
- Take advantage of built-ins and pure functions with `Scan`:

  ```
  Scan[(k[#] = Partition[# Range[4], 2]) &, Range[5]]
  ```
- `Map` a function that creates the matrices over a set of inputs:

  ```
  ks = Partition[Range[#, 4 #, #], 2] & /@ Range[5]
  ```