# Syntax question for declaring variables

Tags: syntax

I have a very basic syntax question for declaring $X_{hb}$ a variable.

```
f[Subscript[X, hb_]] := Subscript[X, hb]
```

In mathematica instead of writing the `Subscript[]` code, I simply use the `ctrl+_` shortcut to place whatever I want in the subscript. However, after doing this I do not know how make mathematica consider $X_{hb}$ as a variable since placing the `_` after it is considered to be an unrealted character.

See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGz8F.png

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: 1. Don't use Subscripts. 2. If you won't listen to rule 1, then see this answer to your question (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica)
(http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13741/how-to-create-symbol-whose-name-has-subscript)

Comment: Try `f[hb_]:=Subscript[X, hb]`.

Comment: @Searke It seems like a very basic thing to do. Why is declaring variables qith subscripts a big no-no in mathematica? It's very common in math to write variables with subscripts. In any case, I am going to follow the "rule 1" as that is a lot of stuff to do for a work around.

Comment: @Ozera Good programming notation is not good math notation. For example, using greek characters for variables in your program is also almost always a terrible idea.

Comment: @Ozera There is a logic behind how Subscripts work in Mathematica. Since subscripts are vague and often interpreted in contradictory ways, Mathematica treats them like generic expressions and requires that you tell it what they mean. Most people don't realize how vague and contradictory their different uses of subscripts tend to be.

Comment: @Searke Ah. I thought in Mathematica using greek letters would be okay. Thank you for your help and information about how subscripts actually work!

Comment: @Ozera You can use greek letters as variables just fine in Mathematica. It's just terrible form to program with undescriptive variable names. Write descriptive variable names. Write "variance" instead of using a sigma. This is a rule to follow in practically any programming language, not just Mathematica.

Comment: I think Greek letters are not a problem in mathematica itself (but is a problem with stack exchange). Instead Subscripts are really a problem. The warning about subscripts is therefore a very good advice.

Comment: okay. Thank you all for the information ^.^!

Comment: @andre undescriptive variable names are one of the worst parts of debugging other people's Mathematica code. In no other language do people so often use single letter variable names. My worst experience was a notebook where someone has used "t", "tau", a gothic version of "t", and an ancient aramaic character that looks like "t" just because he wanted several different variables that all looked liked "t".

Comment: Use [Format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to display the variable `X[hb]` in a subscripted form. `Format[X[hb_]] := Subscript[X, hb]; {X[hb], X[a], X[1]}`

Comment: @Searke Descriptive variables and above all descriptive functions are in the philosophy of Mathematica since the beginning (1980s !) and it's a very good thing (long function names were no more a problem thanks to word completion, at this time other langages were full of cryptic names that make them unusable except for *the* specialist). I'm surprised by your experience.

Comment: Finally, note that you don't declare variables in *Mathematica*. Rather, you assign to them `OwnValues`, `DownValues`, `UpValues`, and `SubValues`.