# Making subscripts with variable

Tags: subscript

How do I make a variable $k_{1x}$ where the $x$ is just a label to denote the magnitude along the x-axis and not an actual defined variable x in the code?

Similarly, if I wanted to make $E_x$ or $E_{0x}$ for electric field notations, not only can I not use a variable subscript, the $E$ is replaced by `Exp`.

Comment: [`E`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html) is a built-in function. You should not use symbol names that start with capital letter to avoid conflicts with build-in functions.

Comment: Ok even if I use q_x, how do I do that?

Comment: Use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) for subscripted variables.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you need?

```
ClearAll[kx, k, x]
Format[kx[n_]] := Subscript[k, n, x]
kx[1]
kx[1] = 5
kx[1]
```

If for some reason you actually need variables with subscripts, see
[How to create symbol whose name has subscript?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13741/how-to-create-symbol-whose-name-has-subscript)

Comment: Would the x be integrated if I did Integral(k_1x) here?

Comment: @NishaMariamJohnson I'm confused.   In your qeustion, you said you wanted `x` as a label, not as a variable.  Are you now saying you want it to be a (bound) variable in an integrand?