# Using sub-scripted variables in functions

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

Is it possible to use subscripts in Mathematica functions, for example

```
  f[Subscript[x, a] _] := x^2
```

However this doesn't seem to work, is there a way to allow indexed variables to behave in the same way as non-indexed variables?

Cheers

Comment: But then, why do you need to do this?

Comment: I just prefer the notion style for readability.

Comment: The best advice about working with `Subscripts` is: don't use them. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica), [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13741/how-to-create-symbol-whose-name-has-subscript), and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/373/clear-complains-that-a-subscripted-variable-is-not-a-symbol-or-a-string).

Comment: @corey979 Duly noted. It can be done, its just probably not worth it. Lesson of the day don't use subscripts.

Comment: @ corey979 This has been the common opinion for many years. However, recently I started to notice that the expressions with subscripts work in situations they have not work before, and started to use subscripts, especially in tensor expressions, being very careful in cross-checking the results with and without subscripts. It seems to work. May it be an improvement of the latest Mma version?