# How make D[f,x] treat OverBar[x] as a constant

Tags: assumptions, operators, calculus-and-analysis

I have an expression of the form `f = a*x +OverBar[x]`, where OverBar[x] is just a name, it has not much to do with the variable x. I want `D[f,x] = a` but Mathematica shows `D[f,x] = a +OverBar'[x]`.

Is there a way to let Mathematica know that OverBar[x] is just a name and it's derivative wrt to x is zero? `D[]` doesn't take `Assumptions` as an option afaik.

Also it does not matter whether I take something else say OverHat or UnderBar the issues is still the same `D[OverHat[x],x] = OverHat'[x]` according to Mathematica.

If nothing helps, is there any notation resembling `OverBar` that does not become a function of its argument? i.e. that it is just a symbol/name.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13741/how-to-create-symbol-whose-name-has-subscript), you just have `OverBar` instead of `Subscript`

Comment: Related: [(91356)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91356/121)

Comment: Could use `Dt`: `In[78]:= Dt[a*x + OverBar[x], x, Constants -> {a, OverBar}]

Out[78]= a`

Answer (score 2):

Just put `OverBar'[p]` or whatever variable to zero after differentiation. Nothing fancy but should do the job. Something like

```
D[f,x]//ReplaceAll[#, OverBar'[x] -> 0] &
```

Or make a list and set all the `OverBar'[par]` in the world to zero, where `par` is any of your (my) parameters.

Comment: No need to do it after differentiation; you can set `OverBar'[x] = 0` at the beginning and it should work too.

Comment: Yup that's right, in some cases that's better.

Comment: Incidentally `D[f,x] /. OverBar'[x] -> 0`

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer not to have to make the replacement each time:

```
OverBar'[x] = 0;

f = a*x + OverBar[x]

D[f, x]
```

> ```
> a*x + OverBar[x]
>
> a
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `OverBar[x]` and `x` together. For example:

```
Solve[a x + OverBar[x] == 2, x] //InputForm
```

> DynamicSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
>
> Solve[a*x + OverBar[x] == 2, x]

However, it is possible to get an object that looks like `OverBar[x]`, but doesn't actually include x. If you entered `OverBar[x]` explicitly as `OverBar[x]` in your code, you could instead use:

```
OverBar[RawBoxes@"x"]
```

> [image]

(I replaced the above output with an image of what one would see in a notebook).

The box structure is identical:

```
ToBoxes[OverBar[x]]
ToBoxes[OverBar[RawBoxes@"x"]]
```

> OverscriptBox["x", "_"]
>
> OverscriptBox["x", "_"]

This construct is completely independent of `x`, so now [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) will work as expected:

```
Solve[a x + OverBar[RawBoxes@"x"] == 2, x]
```

> [image]

(Again, the above is an image)

```
D[a x + OverBar[RawBoxes@"x"], x]
```

> a

Now, it might be that you like to use keyboard shortcuts to create the [`OverBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OverBar.html) object, and the above approach won't work for you. In that case you can add a [`MakeExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression.html) rule as follows:

```
MakeExpression[OverscriptBox["x", "_"], StandardForm] := HoldComplete[OverBar[RawBoxes@"x"]]
```

Now, the object created by the key strokes:

<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>, <kbd>_</kbd>

will be interpreted as the `OverBar[RawBoxes@"x"]` expression I give above.