# Why are scripts not allowed as components of vectors?

Tags: hold, subscript

In Mathematica, I attempted to construct an arbitrary vector $\vec{a}$ using the `Subscript`:

```
a = {Subscript[a, x], Subscript[a, y], Subscript[a, z]}
```

However, Mathematica returns with the following message:

`Hold[{Subscript[a, x],Subscript[a, y], Subscript[a, z]}]`

All I would like to do is to perform vector operations with components of a vector denoted by subscript index.
This comes across as very odd to me given subscripts are non-protected symbols.

Comment: It is not really about the `Subscript` but about the fact that you set a value of `a` which depends of `a`, like: `a = {a, 1}`. Try to rename it: `vector = {Subscript[b, 1], 1}`

Comment: But `a` isn't the same as `Subscript[a,x]` so why does Mathematica sees it this way-and hence, arriving at a conflict?

Comment: " 'a' isn't the same as 'Subscript[a,x]' " - but it is the same `a` here and there, in `Subscript` and on the right hand side of `=`. By the way, `Subscript` is not special so any head will give the same problem, like in the example from the first comment.

Comment: You will save yourself a lot of hassle in the future if you heed the words of item 3 in this post regarding subscripts: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/1783

Comment: The ***message*** actually returned is "$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of Subscript[a, x]."  As Kuba is pointing out, the definition of `a` as a vector is being recursively substituted for `a` in the expression `Subscript[a, x]`.  This would result in an infinite loop if it were not for the internal limit `$RecursionLimit`. Note also, that if `x` has a value, it would be substituted as well; similarly for `y` and `z`.  Look up the Notation package in the docs or on this site, if you wish to use such notation in *Mathematica*.

Comment: You may also want to read this post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50726/can-a-symbol-own-ownvalues-that-dont-evaluate-when-its-the-head-of-an-expressi#comment149900_50726

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to automatically change `Subscript[a, n]` into `Subscript[RawBoxes["a"], n]` to avoid recursion errors. Both `a` and `RawBoxes["a"]` look the same, so you will only notice that they are different by looking at the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html)/[`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of an expression (this is an idea I mentioned previously in [(137993)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138013/45431)). A couple possibilities to do this are:

**If you always enter subscripts using <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd>, then you can use a [`MakeExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression.html) rule:**

```
MakeExpression[SubscriptBox["a", n_], StandardForm] := With[
    {v = HoldComplete[RawBoxes["a"]], sub = MakeExpression[n, StandardForm]},
    Thread[Unevaluated @ Subscript[v, sub], HoldComplete]
]
```

**Or, you can add [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) to [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html):**

```
Subscript /: Subscript[a, n_] := Subscript[RawBoxes@"a", n]
Subscript /: Set[Subscript[a, n_], rhs_] := Subscript[RawBoxes@"a", n] = rhs
```

Depending on your workflow, you may need to do both. Note, however, that overriding built-in symbols in this way can lead to trouble. This is why I've written the above code to only work for `a`, and not for any symbol.

At any rate, now you can do things like:

```
Solve[a + Subscript[a, 1] == 0, a]
D[a + Subscript[a, 1], a]
```

> {{a -> -Subscript[a, 1]}}
>
> 1

as well as your original example:

```
a = {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3]}
a // InputForm
```

> {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3]}
>
> {Subscript[RawBoxes["a"], 1], Subscript[RawBoxes["a"], 2], Subscript[RawBoxes["a"], 3]}

Notice, no recursion errors.

Comment: Carl -- this is really bad advice. Complicated workarounds in order to use subscripts instead of actual symbols is a recipe for disaster. In this scheme you will not even be able to see the problem because `a` and `"a"` look alike.

Comment: Perhaps you can share "the problem" that you are referring to?

Comment: Number 3 here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/1783

Comment: @Carl. This is a highly interesting way for working with subscripted variables (which I never do). A small question: you consider subscripted `RawBoxes["a"]`. It seems to me that you could have used subscripted strings in the same way: `Subscript["a", 3]`. Is there a particular reason for using `RawBoxes`?

Comment: @FredSimons I use TraditionalForm a lot, and in TraditionalForm, a and "a" look different because of SingleLetterItalics.

Comment: @Carl. I see. I rarely use TraditionalForm, so I did not think of that. Thanks.