# Save variables values and definition

Tags: variable-definitions

I used to do a lot of programming in R and recently switched to *Mathematica*. One thing that bothers me is that I haven't found a way to save variables, their values and definition!

Let's look at an example:

```
idx = Partition[RandomSample[Range[20], 20], 3];
Table[Subscript[vars, idx[[i]]] = Total[idx[[i]]], {i, 1, 
Length[idx]}];
Subscript[vars,{9,15,8}]
(*32*)
```

Is there a way to save the variable names as well as the corresponding values. And how would I read them into a new file? So that in a new file I can access with `Subscript[vars,{9,15,8}]` the value.

I tried it with `Table[...]>>values.mx` and read it in with `values=<<values.mx` but that only gives me the values, whereas I also need the definitions. I also tried:

```
DumpSave["values.mx", 
 Table[Subscript[vars, idx[[i]]] = Total[idx[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[idx]}]]
```

but got an error

> DumpSave::bsnosym: "Table[..] is not defined as a symbol or a context"

Comment: Does `DumpSave[ ]` not work properly for you?

Comment: @bills In the last sentence the OP said that he can't get the proper syntax for `DumpSave[]`. Can you help him?

Comment: yes, I didn't geht the syntax right, I tried `DumpSave["values.mx", 
 Table[Subscript[vars, idx[[i]]] = Total[idx[[i]]], {i, 1, 
   Length[idx]}]]` but got an error `(*DumpSave::bsnosym: "Table[..] is not defined as a symbol or a context"*)`

Comment: Hi rainer, you are fighting the syntax here: `Subscript[vars,i]` is not the easy way to do indexing in Mathematica. It is more of a typesetting convenience, that is, for display. The easy thing to do is to have `vars` be a list, and to index into that list. This is the way I answered the question below.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard isn't that post about saving a whole function definition to a file? Whereas here I'm trying to save variable name based on subscript. I already read that post and found out about `DumpSave`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that detail.  You want to save all definitions associated with `vars`, correct?

Comment: Yes,all the definitions and the values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two easy ways I can think of to do this, but both require a change to your methods.

The first is to merely use [indexed objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) instead of `Subscript`, e.g. `vars[1] = x; vars["thing"] = y; . . .`.  You would then use `Save["file.m", vars]`.

The second will allow you to use `Subscript` but you will need to change the way the definitions are made, to attach the definitions to the symbol `vars` rather than `Subscript`.  (Described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1005/121).)

```
vars /: Subscript[vars, n] = . . .
```

This creates `UpValues` on the symbol `vars` which will be saved by `Save["file.m", vars]`.

---

A complete working example:

```
idx = Partition[RandomSample[Range[20], 20], 3];

Table[vars /: Subscript[vars, i] = Total[i], {i, idx}];

Save["vars-test.m", vars];
```

Now check what was saved:

```
FilePrint["vars-test.m"]
```

---

For additional (general) methods of saving definitions see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file/2008#2008).

Comment: @rainer I'm certainly glad we got that figured out.  Thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 2):

Start with your data idx. What you are calculating is the `Total` of each of the triplets in `idx`. Let's do this the easy way and assign it to a variable

```
vars = Map[Total, idx]
```

You can save `vars` to a file like this:

```
DumpSave["test.mx", vars]
```

Then, after quitting and starting again, you can get the saved variables and data back by

```
<<test.x
```

Now, if you want the nth entry of vars, you type

```
 vars[[n]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually it's more difficult than that. I apply another more complicated function. And I do need this specific output because it's an input somewhere else

Comment: You've seen the new integration with R? http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/built-in-integration-with-r/ There's a whole page on how to translate data from Mathematica to R (and back): http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/RLink/tutorial/DataTypes.html