# Solving a system of equations using subscripted variables

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve this equation:

```
X(i, j) + C*Y(i, j) = Z(i, j)
```

Where

```
i = 2    
j = 2
C = 5
X(i, j) = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}
Y(i, j) = {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}
```

How can I get *Mathematica* to solve for values of `Z(1, 1)`, `Z(2, 1)`, `Z(1, 2)`, `Z(2, 2)`?

I’m relatively new the *Mathematica*, and I’d like to solve these 4 equations, but I’d also like to be able to scale up i and j (to say, 10) without rewriting the code. Any syntax help would be very helpful. My code looks like this, but I can’t get *Mathematica* to find the solution.

```
Solve[
  Table[Subscript[X, i, j] - (C*Subscript[Y, i, j]), {i, 2}, {j, 2}] ==
    Table[Subscript[Z, i, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}], {X, Y, Z}]
```

Comment: See this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica

Comment: Thanks David, but I already found that, it didn't answer my question.

Comment: If you just want to do the matrix operation, I think you can do something like this `X = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}; Y = {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}; C0 = 5; Z = X + C0 Y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Mathematica* doesn't allow implicit definition of a matrix, so your `Z` should be defined as something like:

```
Z = {{z1, z2}, {z3, z4}};
```

For the case in which the order of `Z` is very high, you may prefer this kind of definition (just in case, I'd like to mention that something like `Z(1, 1)` doesn't make sense in *Mathematica*):

```
Z = Table[z[i, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
```

Then, you seem to mix up `Subscript` and `List`. They're totally different. Personally, I suggest you not to use `Subscript`, since (I think) it's a compromise to the traditional form of math symbol and a somewhat pathological object in *Mathematica*. You'll find that `List` or just something like `a[1, 1] = 1; a[1, 2] = 2; …` more convinient when you get more familiar with *Mathematica*. Here your `X` and `Y` can be defined like this:

```
X = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
Y = {{2, 2}, {2, 2}};
```

The third problem in your code is that you choose capital letters for the name of variables, it's not a good choice since all the built-in functions in *Mathematica* are begun with capital letter so it may cause problems, and for your code, your `C` gets caught: it's a protected symbol. We can change it into `c`:

```
c = 5;
```

After running all the code above, we can solve your equation (by the way, your syntax of `Solve` is also wrong, it should not be `{X, Y, Z}` because `X` and `Y` are not unknown variables):

```
Solve[X + c Y == Z, Flatten@Z]
(* {{z1 -> 11, z2 -> 11, z3 -> 11, z4 -> 11}} 
   or
   {{z[1, 1] -> 11, z[1, 2] -> 11, z[2, 1] -> 11, z[2, 2] -> 11}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying in your edit.  I need to read and reread this a few times.  I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @user6941 Everything's hard in the beginning :).