# Evaluating terms in series

Tags: summation

I'm trying to evaluate a simple expression:

```
Subscript[λ, n] = (2 n - 1) π/(2 L);
```

And then sum it up:

```
Sum[Subscript[λ, n], {n, 1, 3}]
```

The result is:

> ```
> π/(2 L) + Subscript[λ, 2] + Subscript[λ, 3]
> ```

How can i get *Mathematica* to write the second and third term in the same way as the first?

Comment: Do not understand the question, but may be you wanted this? `lam[n_] := (2 n - 1) Pi/(2 L); Sum[ lam[n], {n, 1, 3}]`

Comment: Yes that would work, but would it be possible to write each term separately?  Like Pi/2L + 3Pi/2L + 5Pi/2L?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to limit evaluation in the sum.  You can use [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html) to accomplish this.  I [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) (`@@`) it to a list for partial evaluation.

```
Subscript[λ, n_] := Defer @@ {(2 n - 1) Pi/2 L};

Sum[Subscript[λ, n], {n, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
> (L π)/2 + (3 L π)/2 + (5 L π)/2
> ```

Or perhaps more to your liking:

```
Subscript[λ, n_] := Defer @@ {(2 n - 1) Pi/Defer[2 L]};

Sum[Subscript[λ, n], {n, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
> π/(2 L) + (3 π)/(2 L) + (5 π)/(2 L)
> ```

By the way, if you are going to use subscripts for function definitions please read [Can we use letter with a subscript as a variable in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica/1005#1005).  A number of users would tell you to avoid them for simplicity.

Comment: This was what I was looking for! Thanks!