# Using subscripted symbols in functions

Tags: custom-notation, subscript

Using subscripts would significantly improve the structure of my code. Until now I used the following two lines to implement this.

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]];
```

This allows me to define a symbol like

```
Subscript[a, r] = 10
```

This works fine up to the point where I want to define e.g.

```
f[r_] = r Subscript[a, r][r]
```

I want the result to be

```
f[x] = 10 x
```

The problem is that *Mathematica* recognizes the `r` in `Subscript[a, r]` as an variable. Hence I can not use the subscript in such a case. Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: Related: [Can me use letter with a subscript as a variable?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/can-we-use-letter-with-a-subscript-as-a-variable-in-mathematica).

Comment: My experience tells me that you will disappointed with the approach you are taking -- introducing subscripted variables will cause more problems than improvements to the structure of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want

```
With[{u = Subscript[a, r]}, f[r_] := u r]
```

then

```
f[x]
```

> ```
> 10 x
> ```

Or perhaps you want to keep `Subscript[a, r]` as a free variable.

```
g[x_] := Subscript[a, r] x
g[x]
```

> ```
> 10 x
> ```

```
Subscript[a, r] = 42; g[x]
```

> ```
> 42 x
> ```