# Quick simplification of a fraction of 2 trigonometric equations

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I would like to simplify a fraction of 2 trigonometric functions

```
EqAng1={Cos[Subscript[β, 0][t]] Sin[Subscript[α, 0][t]] == 
  Cos[Subscript[β, i][t]] Sin[Subscript[α, i][t]], 
 Cos[Subscript[α, 0][t]] Cos[Subscript[β, 0][t]] == 
  Cos[Subscript[α, i][t]] Cos[Subscript[β, i][t]], 
 Sin[Subscript[β, 0][t]] == Sin[Subscript[β, i][t]]}

Simplify[EqAng1[[1]]/EqAng1[[2]]]
```

The result obtained is not simplified.

Is there a function enabling a direct simplification of this fraction with trigonometric functions ?

Comment: Most likely, you want to avoid using subscripts. They are pretty tricky if you do not exactly know what you are doing (that's a general remark). Besides that, `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` work better if you provide `Assumptions`. Also, what do you want to happen to the `Equal`s in your list? Do you want the method to give the condition under which `Equal` returns true?

Comment: How I can remove "the subscripts"  when I cite a piece of code?

Comment: @Lukas If I have eq1: A=B and eq2: C=D with A,B,C,D trigonometric expressions, i wanted to know if there is a function which can do eq1/eq2 which can give A/B=C/D

Comment: It was not just about getting rid of the subscripts in the question, I meant to not use them in your code. They are not used like symbols, see e.g. here (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1004/21606). So you just want to rewrite your equations? Would `rewrite[eq1_,eq2_]:=eq1[[1]]/eq1[[2]]==eq2[[1]]/eq2[[2]]`be what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Format[α[i_]] := Subscript[α, i];
Format[β[i_]] := Subscript[β, i];

EqAng1 = {
   Cos[β[0][t]] Sin[α[0][t]] == 
    Cos[β[i][t]] Sin[α[i][t]],
   Cos[α[0][t]] Cos[β[0][t]] == 
    Cos[α[i][t]] Cos[β[i][t]],
   Sin[β[0][t]] == Sin[β[i][t]]};
```

You cannot divide one equation by another. Define a function to do what you want.

```
divideEqn[eqn1_Equal, eqn2_Equal] :=
  eqn1[[1]]/eqn2[[1]] == eqn1[[-1]]/eqn2[[-1]];

divideEqn[EqAng1[[1]], EqAng1[[2]]]
```

[image]

```
divideEqn[EqAng1[[1]], EqAng1[[3]]]
```

[image]

```
divideEqn[EqAng1[[2]], EqAng1[[3]]]
```

[image]