# How do I clear all variables with subscripts?

Tags: clear

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clear complains that a variable is not a symbol or a string?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/373/clear-complains-that-a-variable-is-not-a-symbol-or-a-string)

`Clear["Global`*"]` Works for most variables, however if i do something like

$ \delta_a = \alpha_a \Delta T d $

Then the `Clear` or `ClearAll` will not clear $ \delta_a $, short of `Quit[]` is there anything that can be done to clear variables with subscripts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well. You can always clear a certain value by using `Unset`

```
Subscript[r, 3]=8;
Subscript[r, 3]=.;
```

Now, `Clear` and `ClearAll` won't work if you used regular `=` and assigned the values as `Subscript`'s `DownValues`. But if you used `UpValues`, it could work

```
r/:Subscript[r, 3]=8;
ClearAll[r];
```

Answer (score 9):

Try [`Remove`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Remove.html).

```
Subscript[x, k_] = 1/k^2;
Clear[x]
Subscript[x, 2]
Remove[x]
Subscript[x, 2]
```