# How to "clear" the downvalues of a subscripted variable?

Tags: downvalues, clear, subscript

I have a function that sets certain subscripts of the symbol aa as in the following example:

```
listA = { Subscript[aa,2], Subscript[aa,1,4,7], Subscript[aa,2,4,5,8] };
listB = {1,2,3};
Evaluate[listA]=listB
```

This causes `Subscript[aa,2] = 1`, etc. Later I wish to reuse the function, sometimes with some of the same downvalues of aa. But, first I must unset those downvalues.

I know I can clear ALL subscripted variables using Clear [ "Subscript" ]. But I need to clear only the subscripted values of the symbol aa while leaving other subscripted symbols alone. Is there a way to do something like the following?

Clear [ "Subscript[ aa ]" ]   or   Subscript[aa,u__]=.  or
  clear downvalues of aa

I suppose I could consider learning the Notation package, but all my functions involving subscripts are now working. I am just having this problem of re-using them during a single session.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: This is one of the reasons that experienced users of *Mathematica* caution new users to *only* use `Subscript`s for display purposes, and not for calculational purposes. It is standard practice to use, e.g. `aa[1]`, `aa[1, 4, 7]`, etc. in place of the `Subscript`ed versions. You can use `Format` to have the front end display `aa[1]` as a subscript while having it be `aa[1]` in the back end.

Comment: matrixbud, it seems you have been given @march's advice before on some of your other questions about `Subscript`s. Are you starting to see why using them as you are is discouraged? Is the effort really worth it compared to switching to `aa[1]` etc.? :p

Comment: Oh, yes, I quite see! Live and learn. However I am so close to being finished with this part of my project that I hate to think of modifying all my code. On the flip side, through this forum I have learned a LOT of Mathematica (and, I've learned how much I don't know.) At this point, I hope I can reach the finish line without recoding the whole thing without subscripts. Else, I will use march's front-end/back-end advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will remove all `DownValues` of `Subscript` that contain the symbol `aa`:

```
DownValues[Subscript] = Cases[DownValues[Subscript], dv_ /; FreeQ[dv, aa]]
```

It won't remove `SubValues`, but those can be removed in a similar way.

You can avoid the trouble with `DownValues` by using `UpValues`, as shown in 
[Clear complains that a subscripted variable is not a symbol or a string?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/373/clear-complains-that-a-subscripted-variable-is-not-a-symbol-or-a-string/379#379), or in
[How do I clear all variables with subscripts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/how-do-i-clear-all-variables-with-subscripts/2236#2236)

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I have only recently learned a little about downvalues and upvalues and so I probably don't understand your reply well enough. Also, I have not heard of subvalues and when I searched Help for SubValues, nothing showed up. But... when I entered my 3 lines of code followed by yours, the values of aa2, aa1,4,7 and aa2,4,5,8 were still set at 1,2, and 3 respectively. I substituted SubValues for DownValues with the same result. To use UpValues, I would have to experiment how to use them with my lists.

Comment: @matrixbud This worked for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gFKgB.png -- Upvalues and subvalues won't help in this particular case.

Comment: I stand corrected. When I copied and pasted you answer, it didn't work. But when I typed it in manually, it works like a charm!! Thanks so much.

Comment: I added a similar 3 lines using symbol bb. And even though I only used your Cases code for aa, bb also got cleared. Your FreeQ looks like it should only select aa, so I don't understand how bb also got cleared.

Comment: @matrixbud I'm not sure what you're doing, but, again, this worked for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hwKse.png

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll play with it. I was trying to say that in my test, your code worked much like Clear["Subscript"] in that it cleared more than just aa. But maybe I'm making mistakes. You've done plenty for me. Thanks.