# Why does Clear[] not work on subscripted variables?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Where is the problem?

[image]

```
Subscript[k, 0] := 1;
Subscript[k, 1] := 2;
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Subscript[k, 0]
Subscript[k, 1]
Clear[Subscript[k, 0]]
Clear[Subscript[k, 1]]
```

Comment: As a general rule I recommend that everyone avoid subscripts and use indexed variables instead, e.g., `k[0]` and `k[1]`. After assigning values the subscripted form would not appear in the output anyway. Prior to assigning values, if you want the subscripted form displayed, use `Format[k[n_]] := Subscript[k, n]` to control the subsequent display.

Comment: @BobHanlon's advice is good advice. I wish subscripts were easier to deal with--they can be so darn useful sometimes. $vars = Indexed[x, #] & /@ Range[5]$  $Grad[f[vars], vars]$

Comment: Please use a descriptive title in the future. "Where is the problem?" gives no hint about the contents of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your definitions are associated with `Subscript` not `k`.

`Subscript` is in the `System` context.  I suspect that

```
(* ClearAll["System`*"] *)
```

would be a bad idea.

You could modify the definition of your symbols, so that they are associated with `k`

```
k /: Subscript[k, 0] := 1;
k /: Subscript[k, 1] := 2;

{Subscript[k, 0], Subscript[k, 1]}
(* {1, 2} *)
```

These can then be cleared

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
{Subscript[k, 0], Subscript[k, 1]}
(* {Subscript[k, 0], Subscript[k, 1]} *)
```

Less drastically

```
Clear[k]
```

also works (don't specify the subscript, because the results isn't a symbol).

Comment: I got it `Subscript` is in the `System` context. Thank you. How to show all subscripts in a notebook? Is there any code such as ```?Global`*  ```  and ```?System`* ```

Comment: `?Subscript` will report subscripts - though I think you will need to click to expand the box containing the symbol information.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very useful answer here: [StackExchange 2017 by Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128498/how-to-clear-the-downvalues-of-a-subscripted-variable) (I shouldn't get credit for this answer...)

```
Subscript[symbol, 1] = 1
Subscript[symbol, 2] = 2
```

Now you see it.

```
Subscript[symbol, 1]
```

Then you clear it by only retaining downvalues that don't depend on symbol

```
DownValues[Subscript] = 
 Cases[DownValues[Subscript], dv_ /; FreeQ[dv, symbol]]
```

Now you don't.

```
Subscript[symbol, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way if you want to clear individual values.

```
Subscript[k, 0] := 1
Subscript[k, 1] := 2
```

You can clear one at a time this way:

```
Subscript[k, 0] =.
```

which clears the first one but leaves the second one alone.

```
Subscript[k, 0]
(*Subscript[k, 0]*)

Subscript[k, 1]
(*2*)
```