# Selectively clear DownValues

Tags: pattern-matching, downvalues

How can I clear a subset of a symbol's `DownValues` ?

For example, suppose I have created some DownValues for $f$ like this:

```
(f[Sequence @@ #] = Plus @@ #) & /@ Subsets[{1, 2, 3}];
f[x_, y_] := x y

DownValues[f]    
(*  {HoldPattern[f[]] :> 0, HoldPattern[f[1]] :> 1, 
 HoldPattern[f[2]] :> 2, HoldPattern[f[3]] :> 3, 
 HoldPattern[f[1, 2]] :> 3, HoldPattern[f[1, 3]] :> 4, 
 HoldPattern[f[2, 3]] :> 5, HoldPattern[f[1, 2, 3]] :> 6, 
 HoldPattern[f[x_, y_]] :> x y}  *)
```

I now wish to clear all the downvalues for which $f$ has exactly $n$ numerical arguments. In other words I would like to have a function `selectiveClear[f,n]` such that this would happen:

```
selectiveClear[f,2]
DownValues[f]
(*  {HoldPattern[f[]] :> 0, HoldPattern[f[1]] :> 1, 
 HoldPattern[f[2]] :> 2, HoldPattern[f[3]] :> 3, 
 HoldPattern[f[1, 2, 3]] :> 6, HoldPattern[f[x_, y_]] :> x y}  *)
```

I have tried using `Cases` to pick a subset of the `DownValues`, but I can't seem to get the pattern correct.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5086749/618728

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the link is very useful too, thanks. I always forget to search on stackoverflow. It would be nice if the Mathematica questions on there could be imported into this site somehow.

Comment: They can be imported, but only on a case-by-case basis as they're still generally on-topic over there. We have to beg and plead for them to be migrated, and it rarely happens with questions that are older with good answers already.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
DownValues[f] = 
 DeleteCases[DownValues[f], _@_[_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ] :> _]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[]] :> 0, HoldPattern[f[1]] :> 1, 
>  HoldPattern[f[2]] :> 2, HoldPattern[f[3]] :> 3, 
>  HoldPattern[f[1, 2, 3]] :> 6, HoldPattern[f[x_, y_]] :> x y}
> ```

It is possible to make this pattern fail if you want also to clear something like:

```
f[1, 2] /; $op := "$op is active"
```

This would catch it:

```
DeleteCases[
 DownValues[f],
 (x_ :> _) /; ! x ~FreeQ~ Verbatim[f][_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ]
]
```

---

Szabolcs remarks it is valuable to mention `Unset` in this context.
[I described the use of that and related functions here.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/379/121)

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed. I've used `Repeated[_?NumericQ,{n}]` to get a function that removes downvalues with `n` arguments.

Comment: @Simon glad I could help.  That is a good generalization.