# How to get the list of defined values for an indexed variable?

Tags: data-structures, downvalues

I would like a table with rational indexes - thus it would be practical to use a dictionary, which, in Mathematica are implemented with the indexed variables. I would like to be able to do:

```
...
If[a[1/2] is defined, a[1/2] = a[1/2] + 1, a[1/2] = 1]
...
If[a[4568/8746] is defined, a[4568/8746] = a[4568/8746] + 1, a[4568/8746] = 1]
...
```

and then further along:

```
ConvertToList[a] -> {... {1/2, 4}, {4568/8746, 9}, ... }
```

Had my indexes been integers, I could have used the built-in function `Array`. But they are not, thus at some point, I need to get a list of all the indexes for which `a`has a value. I could hack a solution (for instance: implement my own dictionary structure, or keeping a set of all values I defined and use it to know where I should look), but this seems silly. Especially since Mathematica provides the functionality I desire as a meta-function:

```
?a
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to make use of it programmatically.

How can I do what I want? Am I wrong to think that indexed variables are the way to do it?

---

**UPDATE:** Thank you so much for your extremely informative answers---I admit I wish I were able to accept *both* of them! Especially as they both give complementary information.

To give a little bit more information on my usage, I have both been looking for this general functionality for some time (a generic hash table type structure), but the example I suggested is a real-world example not a minimal one :)

As a first approach (because I can't get an easy formula), I am computing the probability distribution function of the ratio of two discrete random variables. To do this, I am iterating over all values of the first random variable, and then iterating over all values the second one can take (which depend on the value of the first random variable). I then complete the table using as index the ratio of the two random variables. The problem is there are great many rationals and that $1/2$ is the same as $2/4$, etc., hence the reason for using a hash table.

I had already managed a clunky way of doing this, but now I have a very fast function, thanks to you two, that allows me to get the PDF of my distribution. It is then convenient to convert this to a CDF of the distribution to avoid the many fluctuations inherent to the discrete rational distribution.

You are both deeply thanked for your explanations.

Comment: Have you seen `DownValues[]`?

Comment: You might also want to look at [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1029/5) by Oleksandr for creating a hash table. It might be helpful depending on the use case (and how often you query/update)

Answer (score 9):

The two key functions you need to know to do what you want are:

- [`ValueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ValueQ.html) to test if your symbol has a value or not and
- [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html) to get a list of rules for the definitions (some kinds, anyway)

With these, here's a barebones implementation that should give you the idea. Here `a` is the database, `f` is the function to query values from `a` (and set it if not already defined) and `g` retrieves the indices and their associated values:

```
ClearAll[a, f, g]
f[x : _Integer | _Rational] /; ValueQ[a[x]] := a[x] += 1
f[x : _Integer | _Rational] := a[x] = 1
g[a_Symbol] := DownValues[a] /. (HoldPattern[_[_[x_]]] :> y_) :> {x, y}
```

Here's some sample usage:

```
(* index for which a is not defined *)
f[2]
(* 1 *) 

(* set value for a[3] *)
a[3] = 2;

(* query a[3] and update it in the process *)
f[3]
(* 3 *)

(* retrieve indices and their values *)
g[a]
(* {{2, 1}, {3, 3}} *)
```

Comment: I was in process of trying to answer when RMs answer appeared. An alternative is to define f[x_] := If[IntegerQ[a[x]], a[x] = a[x] + 1, a[x] = 1] in place of the two f's. This is closer to the original posters form and leads to the same kind of thing. This relies on the fact that the values of a[x] are always integers (if they're defined).

Comment: @bills They can be rationals too, not just integers. `If` could be an alternative too, but I like this form for its extensibility (the question seemed like a very minimal example and not really a real world application)

Comment: A side question about `g[a_Symbol] := DownValues[a] /. (HoldPattern[_[_[x_]]] :> y_) :> {x, y}`. Why is it not like `(HoldPattern[_[x_]] :> y_) :> {x, y}`, as `Downvalues` returns somthing like `{HoldPattern[a[2]] :> 1}`?

Answer (score 8):

#### Define a default or background for the hash

I would like to propose a different approach, which is to define a default or generic value for `a`.

If there is not a consistent background value you may use:

```
a[_] = "Empty";

If[a[1/2] =!= "Empty", a[1/2] += 1, a[1/2] = 1]
```

If you can define a constant (or structured) background for your table such as `1`, you can simplify this to:

```
b[_] = 1;

b[1/2] += 1
b[3/4] -= 1.8
```

> ```
> 2
>
> -0.8
> ```

#### Reading the "hash table"

To read the full hash table you can use `DownValues` (see section below) and one of several methods depending on your intent.

You might use a pattern like [the one I used here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7973/121) to return a select set of values:

```
Cases[DownValues@b, (_@_@key_?NumericQ :> val_) :> {key, val}]
```

> ```
> {{1/2, 2}, {3/4, -0.8}}
> ```

You might use `Part` to efficiently extract all values (if pattern-free keys are used the last rule will be the background `b[_]` so it is skipped with `;; -2`):

```
{#[[;; -2, 1, 1, 1]], #[[;; -2, 2]]}\[Transpose] & @ DownValues @ b
```

> ```
> {{1/2, 2}, {3/4, -0.8}}
> ```

#### Related information

The long form of `?a` is `Information[a]`, but this only prints the definition rather than returning it (it returns `Null`).  Closer is `ToString[Definition[a], InputForm]` which returns the definition as printed by `Information` in the form of a `String`.

Deeper down you can access [the Value lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingValueLists.html) such as `OwnValues`, `DownValues`, `SubValues`, `UpValues`, `NValues`, etc.  Unlike `Information` and `Definition` these return lists of equivalent replacement rules.

(If you want to find the definition for a specific value I recommend [my step evaluation function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121).)

Finally, you can check to see if an expression has a value with [`ValueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ValueQ.html), but be sure to read this:

- [Implementing a safe ValueQ that does not evaluate its argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1474/121)

Comment: You could use a default of `a[_]=Sequence[]` and the code then becomes `++a[1/2]`

Comment: Thank you for the additional information on how to to access Value lists.

Comment: @SimonWoods Sadly that won't work with `SubtractFrom` but it's great otherwise.  Any clever solution to *that* problem?