# Constructing an Array from typed expression

Tags: programming, syntax, subvalues

I want to produce an array from expressions given by

```
test[one][1] = 3;
. 
.
test[one][5] = 7;
```

etc.

Normally would use `Table[test[one][i], {i,N}]`, but for this you need the value of `N` that may not be known (without keeping track of it via some other means). I would like to be able to read the maximum value of the integer inside `test[one][ ]` and use this to construct the array. For expression such as `test[1] = 5`, this is straight forward since `DownValues[test]` can be used, but when adding another level the head becomes "test" and `DownValues[]` will not work.

Comment: Related: [(9440)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9440/121); [Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html#1170200440) on different *Values types.

Answer (score 4):

The issue at hand is that curried values are stored in `SubValues`, not `DownValues`:

```
Do[test["one"][i] = Fibonacci[i], {i, 5}];
Last /@ SubValues[test]
(* {1, 1, 2, 3, 5} *)
```

If you have several definitions for `test` such as `test["two"]` or whatever, then you can pattern match on the `SubValues`:

```
Do[test["one"][i] = Fibonacci[i], {i, 5}];
Do[test["two"][i] = Fibonacci[i], {i, 6, 10}];
Cases[SubValues[test], x : test["two"][_] :> x, Infinity]
```

Comment: Yes, thanks that's the function I was looking for