# What is this Counts[] output format?

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to create a list of the distinct elements in a list along with the number of times each appears.

The function Counts[] is supposed to do this, but it puts the results in some weird format I've never seen before and don't know how to use.

```
nn = RandomInteger[5, 200];
Counts[Sort[nn]];

(* <|0 -> 36, 1 -> 30, 2 -> 31, 3 -> 33, 4 -> 36, 5 -> 34|> *)
```

And OF COURSE the online-documentation on Counts[] doesn't cover this topic AT ALL (grumble, grumble)...

So, I hacked my own function to do the counts and put them in a nice array:

```
a = Gather[Sort[nn]];
Table[{a[[i, 1]], Length[a[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length[a]}]

(* {{0, 36}, {1, 30}, {2, 31}, {3, 33}, {4, 36}, {5, 34}} *)
```

But what is that output format that Counts[] returns?  How can I access the numbers in it?

Comment: That is a pretty useful type introduced in MMA 10, `Association`. check it out, you will like it.

Comment: You can also use `Tally` e.g. `Tally[Sort@nn]`

Comment: The documentation for `Counts` says (in the Details section) "Counts[list] gives an association whose keys are in the same order as they first occur as elements of list.", so you then look up `Association` and all is revealed. However, I agree with you that the documentation could be improved, e.g. Wolfram should add an explicit link to `Association`.

Comment: @StephenLuttrell  Ah.  Yes, I saw that, but I didn't realize that by "association" they were referring to a specific data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very connivent function introduced in *Mathematica* v10. The old solution of hash table is presented at: [How to get the list of defined values for an indexed variable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9440/how-to-get-the-list-of-defined-values-for-an-indexed-variable) Now you can do it with `Association` pretty easy.

```
nn = RandomInteger[5, 200];
c = Counts[nn]
(*<|1 -> 37, 4 -> 43, 0 -> 30, 3 -> 36, 2 -> 28, 5 -> 26|>*)
c[0]
(*30*)
```

Comment: Ah.  So, you don't really need to do the Sort[] that you have in there, if I understand this correctly.

Comment: @JerryGuern Yes, no need. I just copy your code.