# Get DownValues that do not involve patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching, downvalues

Say I have a function with a few definitions that also implements memoization:

```
f[x_] := f[x] = x^2
f[x_, y_] := f[x, y] = x^2 + y^2
```

I then apply the function to some data:

```
f /@ {1, 2, 3}
f @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

Now the function will have a bunch of `DownValues` both for the stored results and for the pattern based definitions. Is there some easy way to retrieve only all the stored result, leaving out the pattern based definitions?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(7972)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7972/121), [(9440)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9440/121), and [one on StackOverflow.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5086749/618728)

Comment: one way of extracting the inputs/outputs: `Cases[DownValues[f], (_[Verbatim[f][value : Except[_Pattern]]] :> 
    result_) :> (value -> result)]` (general note: i figure this out by using `FullForm`. e.g. `FullForm[x_] => Pattern[x, Blank[]]`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `FreeQ` and select only those down-values that are free of `Pattern`:

```
Select[DownValues@f, FreeQ[#, Pattern] &]
(* {HoldPattern[f[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f[2]] :> 4, HoldPattern[f[3]] :> 9, 
    HoldPattern[f[1, 2]] :> 5, HoldPattern[f[3, 4]] :> 25} *)
```

Comment: R.M please see my comment above.  Do you think this is a duplicate?  It's not exact but I think the earlier answer also answer this one.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't think it's a duplicate, because Simon's question was about clearing DVs with exactly $n$ arguments. It so happens that your code (with slight modification) would do this, but I don't think it would be obvious to a user who reads it thinking it's a dupe. Simon's (the Aussie one) question on SO though, is an almost dupe — if it had been on this site, I would've probably closed as a duplicate w/ a comment explaining the minor change needed. In any case, if this eventually gets closed, so be it :)

Comment: +1 on Q&A in light of this not being a proper duplicate.

Comment: Depending on how you interpret the question, you could potentially use `Free[#[[1]],Pattern]&` to only select the patterns that don't involve pattern-matching, and not sort out those that might return a pattern or use a pattern in it's definition. For instance `f[b]=a_:>a

Comment: Nice! This also seems to be the faster solution when the number and size of the `DownValues` get big.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative

```
SetAttributes[getImmediateDownvalues, {HoldFirst, Listable}];
getImmediateDownvalues[sym_Symbol] := 
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{sym}, 
  Module[{tag}, 
   PrependTo[DownValues[sym], HoldPattern[sym[] /; tag] :> Null];
   TakeWhile[
    DownValues[
     sym], ! MatchQ[#, Verbatim@HoldPattern[sym[] /; tag] :> _] &]]]
```

So

```
getImmediateDownvalues[f]
(* {HoldPattern[f[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f[2]] :> 4, 
 HoldPattern[f[3]] :> 9, HoldPattern[f[1, 2]] :> 5, 
 HoldPattern[f[3, 4]] :> 25} *)
```