# How to clear all definitions matching f[1, ...] but not f[2, ...]?

Tags: pattern-matching, variable-definitions, clear

I would like to clear all definitions of the form `f[1,...]` in such a way that `f[2,...]` remain unaffected.

The two methods I know to clear variables don't seem to apply to this situation:

1. Pattern matching with `Clear`:

   `Clear[f[1,"*"]]` or `Clear["f[1,*]"]`
2. Using the command `=.`

   `f[1,"*"]=.`

The second option works for particular values of `f[1,...]` but doesn't work with pattern matching.

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: [(7972)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7972/121), [(19536)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19536/121)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can modify `DownValues[f]` directly. For example

```
DownValues[f] = 
 DeleteCases[DownValues[f], HoldPattern[_[f[1, ___]]] :> _]
```

Comment: This works, but I'm a bit confused about the syntax `_[...]`. Could you explain why the `f[1,___]` needs brackets around it in this context?

Comment: @WillG we need to match the `HoldPattern` as it appears in the DownValues, but without putting  it explicitly in the pattern provided to DeleteCase. So we use a Blank. In other words, `_[...]` matches `HoldPattern[...]` but doesn't act as a held pattern. It looks confusing because then we have to wrap the pattern in `HoldPattern` to avoid evaluating the pattern.

Comment: Ok I think I see. So the `HoldPattern` that appears explicitly in `HoldPattern[_[f[1,___]]]` is not what gets matched against the `HoldPattern` stored in `DownValues`?

Comment: @WillG exactly.