# Pack Solve results into a vector

Tags: function-construction, matrix, linear-algebra, vector

I am currently using a really easy function to get the eigenvectors of a corresponding eigenspace:

```
Eigenspace[mat_, ev_] := 
   Solve[
       (mat - IdentityMatrix[Part[Dimensions[mat], 1]] * ev) .
           Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, Part[Dimensions[mat], 1]}]
       == Table[0, {i, Part[Dimensions[mat], 1]}
   ]
]
```

where `ev` is the representation of one eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the matrix $A$. So this is basically my first function I ever wrote based on the knowledge that $E_\lambda=\ker(A-I_n\cdot\lambda)$.

My example matrix is

$$C=\frac{1}{49}\cdot \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 9 & -48 & 4 \\
 36 & 4 & -33 \\
 32 & 9 & 36 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and I can compute `Eigenspace[C, 1]` and get $\left\{\left\{x_1\to \frac{x_3}{2},x_2\to -\frac{x_3}{3}\right\}\right\}$ and I do substitute $x_3$ as it is a free parameter with `Eigenspace[C, 1] /. Subscript[x, 3] -> 1` and get $\left\{\left\{x_1\to \frac{1}{2},x_2\to -\frac{1}{3}\right\}\right\}$.

How can I now return with my function the appropriate eigenvector $(1/2,\;-1/3,\; 1)^T$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, two suggestions:

- I would strongly recommend not using subscripts the way you have used. They can lead to several issues if you're not aware of how subscripts are handled (for instance, when you [try to clear them](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/373/5)). It is best to use them only for typesetting purposes. Use `DownValues` instead.
- Use `Block` to localize `x` so that it is not affected by prior assignments to `x`.

Combining these, you just need to use replacement rules in the right order to get your answer. Here's a modification of your attempt:

```
Clear@Eigenspace
Eigenspace[mat_, ev_] := Block[{x}, 
    With[{vec = Table[x[i], {i, Length@mat}], n = Length@mat}, 
        vec /. Solve[(mat - IdentityMatrix[n] ev).vec == 0 vec] /. x[n] -> 1
    ]
]
```

Using it on your example:

```
Eigenspace[1/49 {{9, -48, 4}, {36, 4, -33}, {32, 9, 36}}, 1]
(* {{1/2, -(1/3), 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a matrix:

[image]

Your function can be written as

```
Eigenspace[mat_, ev_] := Select[Transpose[Eigensystem[mat]], #[[1]] == ev &][[1, 2]]
```

The usage is the same:

```
Eigenspace[m, 1]
```

> {1/2, -(1/3), 1}

It utilizes built-in function `Eigensystem`:

```
Grid[Eigensystem[m], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

So, obviously you just need:

```
Eigensystem[m][[2, 3]]
```

> {1/2, -(1/3), 1}

or

```
Eigenvectors[m][[3]]
```

> {1/2, -(1/3), 1}

this is why and how the Eigenspace function works. Some more elaborate cases - due to @R.M comment.

**----- Case 1 - symbolic -----**

```
m = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10, 10}];
```

pick an eigenvalue:

```
Eigenvalues[m][[3]]
```

> Root[3839155271581433876 + 19229531029350717 #1 - 
>         2777786534122499 #1^2 + 9456285206854 #1^3 + 145246087272 #1^4 - 
>         25506275853 #1^5 - 140468898 #1^6 + 242270 #1^7 - 61201 #1^8 - 
>         427 #1^9 + #1^10 &, 8]

and corresponding vector is

```
Eigenspace[m, %]
```

[image]

**----- Case 2 - numeric -----**

```
m = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}];
```

pick an eigenvalue:

```
Eigenvalues[m][[13]]
```

> -6.12777 - 6.75546 I

and corresponding vector is

```
Eigenspace[m, %]
```

[image]

Comment: @R.M it works ;) See update.

Comment: @Vitality Hehe, I didn't realize that your grid example was only to show how it works... I thought that you were suggesting that he visually scan for the right part and pick that out, hence the comment :D

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
Eigenspace[mat_, ev_] :=
 Module[{vars = 
    Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, Part[Dimensions[mat], 1]}]}, 
  vars /. Solve[(mat - 
        IdentityMatrix[Part[Dimensions[mat], 1]]*ev).vars == 
     Table[0, {i, Part[Dimensions[mat], 1]}]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have been missed that `NullSpace[]` is a built-in function:

```
mat = {{9, -48, 4}, {36, 4, -33}, {32, 9, 36}}/49;

evs = Eigenvalues[mat]
   {I, -I, 1}

NullSpace[mat - # IdentityMatrix[Length[mat]]] & /@ evs
   {{{-18/13 + 14 I/13, 12/13 + 21 I/13, 1}},
    {{-18/13 - 14 I/13, 12/13 - 21 I/13, 1}},
    {{1/2, -1/3, 1}}}
```

Since `NullSpace[]` returns a list of vectors instead of a single vector (as it should), one might want to execute `Flatten[%, 1]` afterwards to get the eigenvectors as a list of vectors. Note that the result in this case matches the output of `Eigenvectors[mat]`.