# How to assign (and retrieve) variables with subscripts?

Tags: variable-definitions

I like to give subscripts to my variable names when the variables are related. I.e.,

```
Subscript[r, i] = 3
```

> 3

A problem arises when I later assign `r` to a value and want to use `Subscript[r,i]` again.

```
r = 6
```

> 6

```
Subscript[r, i]
```

> Subscript[6, i]

Is there any way for me to get the value I assigned to `Subscript[r,i]`? Is this the wrong way to use Mathematica?

Comment: [#5 here is relevant](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/1517)

Comment: [very similar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/373/clear-complains-that-a-subscripted-variable-is-not-a-symbol-or-a-string?rq=1) (duplicate?)

Comment: Please read the documentation for `Notations` and `Symbolize`

Comment: This [pitfall discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18456/3066) is also relevant.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I'll try to avoid doing this in the future. Unfortunately, this is why I use Mathematica. If I can't do this, then I'll most likely stick with another language.