# How to prevent function from substituting the part of the parameter name if it has a subscript?

Tags: functions, replacement

I have the following problem, when defining and using a function, that's supposed to have an outside parameter xmin:

```
A[x_] := Exp[-x/Subscript[x, min]]
A[5]
```

> E^(-(5/Subscript[5, min]))

What can I do about it? I do not really want to rename the parameter to xmin ;)

Comment: You could use `Subscript["x", "min"]` instead of `Subscript[x, min]`

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this duplicate [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34062/18476]

Comment: Karsten.7, thank you for help! I was quite sure it is a duplicate, but the similar questions where more complicated, so I made a mistake and quickly posted the question.