# Error entering equation in DSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, clear, faq

I entered a command incorrectly as follows:

```
    DSolve[{y'[x]=y[x]},y[x],x]
```

I am now experiencing:

```
    DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]}, y[x], x]
```

> During evaluation of In[26]:= DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {True}. >>

```
(* DSolve[{True},y(x),x] *)
```

How do I recover from this error. I've tried `Clear[y'[x]]`. That didn't work.

Comment: `Remove[y]` will do the trick.

Comment: That worked! Thanks.

Comment: Related: [(373)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/373/121)

Comment: @rasher I caution against using `Remove` here!  It will break any definitions that reference `y`, and it will alter even localized appearances of the Symbol, though the definitions may still work.  Try e.g. `fn[y_] := Sin[y]; Remove[y]; Definition[fn]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Good point. Probably gave too quick-n-dirty, emphasis on dirty, solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is for situations like this that [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unset.html) exists. :-)

After the mistaken `Set` operation:

```
y'[x] = "oh dear";

y'[x]
```

> ```
> "oh dear"
> ```

Merely use:

```
y'[x] =.
```

The definition is cleared:

```
y'[x]
```

> ```
> y'[x]
> ```

Please see halirutan's answer for an explanation of why `ClearAll[y]` does not work here.

Answer (score 15):

Very tricky mistake because hard to track down. The problem is that `y'[x]` parses as

```
Derivative[1][y][x]
```

Therefore, your assignment is not to the symbol `y` but to the symbol `Derivative` and since you have multiple call like `f[][]` it goes into its `SubValues`:

```
SubValues[Derivative]
(* {HoldPattern[Derivative[1][y][x]] :> y[x]} *)
```

Therefore, evaluate

```
SubValues[Derivative] = {};
```

and the sun shines again

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]}, y[x], x]
(* {{y[x] -> E^x C[1]}} *)
```

Comment: If there are any other SubValues defined for `Deritative` this non-specific clearing will not be appropriate.  In version 7 for example there are definitions for `InverseLaplaceTransform` by default.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, you are of course right. My answer was rather an explanation what happens than the correct way to solve the problem. I upvoted your answer, since `Unset` is the way to go IMO

Comment: I added a note to my answer directing readers to yours, because they are complementary.

Comment: I just noticed that technically this answer was incorrect.  *Evaluation* of `y'[x]` is not the issue as one can see with `HoldPattern[y'[x]] = "bad"`; rather `y'[x]` *parses* as `Derivative[1][y][x]`, as seen with `HoldForm @ FullForm[y'[x]]`.  I am editing this answer accordingly.