# DSolve ordinary differential equation initial conditions not working 11.2

Tags: differential-equations

I have a differential equation that I want solved using initial conditions.

The differential equation is:

```
DSolve[{y''[x] == (g (A*y[x]*p - m))/m}, y[x], x]
```

which outputs `{{y[x] -> m/(A p) + E^((Sqrt[A] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[p] x)/Sqrt[m]) C[1] + E^(-((Sqrt[A] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[p] x)/Sqrt[m])) C[2]}}`

I want to have the initial conditions `y'[0]==0, y[0]==0`.
When putting in:

```
DSolve[{y''[x] == (g (A*y[x]*p - m))/m, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 0} , y[x], x]
```

I get the error message `DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {(y'')[x]==(g (-m+A p y[x]))/m,True,True}`.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with it as it looks exactly what the mathematica examples have with initial conditions.

Comment: Works fine on my Mac using v11.2, Start with a fresh kernel. You probably have some old definitions hanging around.

Comment: As @BobHanlon, make sure that all the symbols to be used are fresh. To that end, one method is to put this code before `DSolve`: `Clear[y, g, A, p, m, x]`.

Comment: This works fine in my computer too. For possible reason of this error, you may have a look at this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80210/error-with-using-ndsolve

Comment: If I run the same thing on my computer: DSolve[{y''[x] == (g (A*y[x]*p - m))/m, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 0} , y[x], x], Then I get the solution without any warning as:$$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to -\frac{m e^{-\frac{\sqrt{A} \sqrt{g} \sqrt{p} x}{\sqrt{m}}} \left(e^{\frac{\sqrt{A} \sqrt{g} \sqrt{p} x}{\sqrt{m}}}-1\right)^2}{2 A p}\right\}\right\}$$