# What is the meaning of the error message "Set::write: Tag Plus in … is Protected"?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

i'm trying to solve system of 9 coupled linear differential equations.I've this problem ... what is it's meaning?
[image]

Comment: Go ahead and post the code that leads to the error.

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour]**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Potential duplicates: [Set::write posts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Set%3A%3Awrite%22) -- Sorry no time to sift them....Ahmed, have you seen them?

Comment: You probably used a = somewhere where a == would have been appropriate.

Comment: More potential duplicates: [error `deqn` posts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=*DSolve+deqn); in particular, [(40314)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40314/).  Hard to tell, with the question in its current incomplete state.  Have you searched for these things?  Do any solve your problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are likely using `=` ([`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)) instead of `==` ([`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)) in the equations you are feeding to `DSolve`. You need to use `==`, which is an equality test. Instead, you're trying to assign the right-hand side (presumably zero) to the linear combinations of `A`s reported by `Set::write`. These linear combinations have the overall head `Plus`, which means that you're ultimately telling Mathematica something like

```
Set[Plus[...],0]
```

Here `Plus` is [`Protected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html), which means that `Set` can't assign it to anything - hence the error as reported.